# How to log PostgreSQL queries?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, logging

How to enable logging of all SQL executed by PostgreSQL 8.3?

*Edited (more info)*
I changed these lines :

```
log_directory = 'pg_log'                    
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'
log_statement = 'all'
```

And restart PostgreSQL service... but no log was created...
I'm using Windows Server 2003.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is important: ```logging_collector = on```

Comment: Also, beware that on some GNU/Linux distributions (e.g. Debian Jessie) `systemctl restart postgresql` may not actually restart PostgreSQL service you have configured (I don't understand why yet), so changes in the configuration file won't be applied.  It is safer to use `pg_ctl` (or `pg_ctlcluster` on Debian).

Comment: I just tested this in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with PostgreSQL 9.5, and `systemctl reload postgresql`, `systemctl restart postgresql`, `service postgresql reload` and `service postgresql restart` all render configuration changes effective.

Comment: In my case (Win 10 desktop, pg12) I had to explicitly enable logging for the actual database using `ALTER DATABASE` (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries#45563564))

Answer (score 553, accepted):

In your `data/postgresql.conf` file, change the `log_statement` setting to `'all'`.

---

**Edit**

Looking at your new information, I'd say there may be a few other settings to verify:

- make sure you have turned on the `log_destination` variable
- make sure you turn on the `logging_collector`
- also make sure that the `log_directory` directory already exists inside of the `data` directory, and that the postgres user can write to it.

Comment: So just curious, does that mean PostgreSQL can't enable logging unless I restart the server? In MySQL, it is as simple as "SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';"

Comment: I myself don't know if there's a way to do it using a SQL statement like MySQL, but you can send a running server a command to reload the config with `pg_ctl reload`

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have a way to change its parameters via SQL statements yet (as of 9.2).  Most logging parameters can be changed without a full server restart, by just doing pg_ctl reload instead.  However, it takes a restart to change logging_collector.

Comment: With Postgres 9.4 and the new [`ALTER SYSTEM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altersystem.html) command a superuser can set GUC params from SQL.

Comment: FWIW - If you do the above 3 things, it works. That is:
`logging_collector = on`, `log_destination = 'stderr'`, `log_statement = 'all'`

I was missing `log_destination`, and it wasn't working.

Comment: What about trigger functions? Can they be logged?

Comment: The `data` directory cited in the answer is not its literal name; it refers to the path assigned to the `data_directory` variable in the PostgreSQL configuration file. On Debian and Ubuntu GNU/Linux, this file usually resides at `/etc/postgresql/$v/main/postgresql.conf`, where `$v` is the server version. Also, on the aforementioned systems, when `log_destination = 'stderr'`, the output is written to `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-$v-main.log`, where `$v` is the server version (not to some location inside `data_directory`).

Comment: In postgres 10, the folder is now called just "log" and postgres made it automatically for me (at least on macos)

Comment: For those using Docker: if you don't want to create a configuration file just to enable logging then add this to your docker-compose.yml:
`command: postgres -c 'log_statement=all'`

Comment: For the reload, `SELECT pg_reload_conf()` might work; the bundled `postgresql.conf.sample` says: *If you edit the file on a running system, you have to SIGHUP the server for the changes to take effect, run "pg_ctl reload", or execute "SELECT pg_reload_conf()".  Some parameters, which are marked below, require a server shutdown and restart to take effect.*

Comment: Scratch `SELECT pg_reload_conf()` and `pg_ctl reload`; in my case only the service reload did the trick. It appears that the logging setting only applies to *new* connections (i.e. those that are already alive - such as from a connection pool - remain in non-logging state) so until you terminate and recreate them you are probably not going to see the logs that you want to see; which is kind of the whole point in enabling logging!

Comment: Isn't this kinda wrong ? It only logs FAULTY queries. I want to read EVERY query, including the ones that successfully ran. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 152):

Edit your `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf`, and change the lines as follows.

**Note**: If you didn't find the `postgresql.conf` file, then just type `$locate postgresql.conf` in a terminal

1. `#log_directory = 'pg_log'` **to** `log_directory = 'pg_log'`
2. `#log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'` **to** `log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'`
3. `#log_statement = 'none'` **to** `log_statement = 'all'`
4. `#logging_collector = off` **to** `logging_collector = on`
5. **Optional**: `SELECT set_config('log_statement', 'all', true);`
6. `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart` **or** `sudo service postgresql restart`
7. Fire query in postgresql `select 2+2`
8. Find current log in `/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/pg_log/`

The log files tend to grow a lot over a time, and might kill your machine. For your safety, write a bash script that'll delete logs and restart postgresql server.

Thanks @paul , @Jarret Hardie , @Zoltán , @Rix Beck , @Latif Premani

Comment: On debian stretch, I also had to uncomment `# log_destination = 'stderr'` in the configuration file before this worked.

Comment: I've following your step carefully and it doesn't works. Does it need restart?

Comment: if you don't want to write a bash script but just want the logs to overwrite monthly do this: `log_filename = 'postgresql-%d.log'` and no it won't overwrite after each restart, it will append for each day and overwrite each month. Of course there are different days depending on month 28,29,30,31 -- but you get the idea.

Comment: I discovered you can run `select pg_reload_config();` since Postgres 9.0 rather than restarting the service in step 6.

Comment: It might be worth nothing that changing `logging_collector = on` requires a server restart - i.e. running `SELECT pg_reload_conf();` will work with the other `postgresql.conf` parameters, but not that one - you can check this by running `SELECT name, pending_restart FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'logging_collector';` after the reload. It's a pity - I'd consider that a niggle at best or a bug at worst.

Answer (score 101):

FYI: The other solutions will only log statements from the default database—usually `postgres`—to log others; start with their solution; then:

```
ALTER DATABASE your_database_name
SET log_statement = 'all';
```

Ref: https://serverfault.com/a/376888 / [`log_statement`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - the only one that has practical value!

Comment: The quoted statements work in Postgres 9.4 or later, but the leading paragraph is false. Setting [`log_statement = all`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT) in `postgresql.conf` for the respective database cluster - like the accepted answer suggests - affects *all* databases of that cluster - which can be overruled by per-database settings.

Comment: reconnect psql to get effect.

Answer (score 54):

```
SELECT set_config('log_statement', 'all', true);
```

With a corresponding user right may use the query above after connect. This will affect logging until session ends.

Comment: It's generally cleaner to use `SET log_statement = 'all'` or (for transaction level) `SET LOCAL log_statement = 'all'`. You might also be interested in the `client_min_messages` and `log_min_messages` settings.

Comment: This is great, since I want to log just the messages of my connection. Unfortunately I get: `permission denied to set parameter "log_statement"` since my user is not superuser.

Comment: You may ask DB administrator for grants executing the function.
`GRANT { EXECUTE | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON { FUNCTION function_name ( [ [ argmode ] [ arg_name ] arg_type [, ...] ] ) [, ...]
         | ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] }
    TO { [ GROUP ] role_name | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]`

Answer (score 42):

You also need add these lines in PostgreSQL and restart the server:

```
log_directory = 'pg_log'                    
log_filename = 'postgresql-dateformat.log'
log_statement = 'all'
logging_collector = on
```

Comment: logging_collector=on is necessary

Comment: Works like a charm. I was confused by the comment on the config file saying `Required to be on for csvlogs`, thinking this option was to log query output and not just statements, but it's not the case.

Comment: In your data/postgresql.conf file, change the log_statement setting to 'all'.

Answer (score 28):

Set `log_statement` to `all`:

[Error Reporting and Logging - log_statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT)

Answer (score 21):

+1 to above answers. I use following config

```
log_line_prefix = '%t %c %u ' # time sessionid user
log_statement = 'all'
```

Answer (score 13):

Just to have more details for CentOS 6.4 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) running PostgreSQL 9.2, based on the instructions found [on this web page](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/log_all_queries_to_a_postgresql_server.html):

1. Set (uncomment) `log_statement = 'all'` and `log_min_error_statement = error` in `/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/postgresql.conf`.
2. Reload the PostgreSQL configuration. For me, this was done by running `/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_ctl reload -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/`.
3. Find today's log in `/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/pg_log/`

Comment: You don't need to *restart* - a `pg_ctl reload` is sufficient, and does not interrupt connections. Not convinced this answer adds anything to those already here.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for the comment, that's quite an important fact. I will update the answer once I've tried your suggestion. I wrote this answer primarily for reference for myself, because at the time I had very little experience with UNIX, and I wanted to have all the necessary information in one place (e.g. the locations of postgresql.conf and the log files).

Answer (score 5):

There is an extension in postgresql for this. It's name is "pg_stat_statements". https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/pgstatstatements.html

Basically you have to change postgresql.conf file a little bit:

```
shared_preload_libraries= 'pg_stat_statements'
pg_stat_statements.track = 'all'
```

Then you have to log in DB and run this command:

```
create extension pg_stat_statements;
```

It will create new view with name "pg_stat_statements". In this view you can see all the executed queries.

Answer (score 5):

You need to run the query below then restart PostgreSQL to enable logging persistently. *The parameter with `ALTER SYSTEM SET` is set to `postgresql.auto.conf` rather than `postgresql.conf`:

```sql
ALTER SYSTEM SET log_statement = 'all';
```

And, you need to run either of the queries below then restart PostgreSQL to disable logging persistently:

```sql
ALTER SYSTEM RESET log_statement;
```

Or:

```sql
ALTER SYSTEM SET log_statement = 'none';
```

You can also run the query below then need to restart PostgreSQL to enable logging persistently:

```sql
ALTER SYSTEM SET log_min_duration_statement = 0;
```

And, you can also run either of the queries below then need to restart PostgreSQL to disable logging persistently:

```sql
ALTER SYSTEM RESET log_min_duration_statement;
```

Or:

```sql
ALTER SYSTEM SET log_min_duration_statement = -1;
```

Be careful, these queries below cannot enable or disable logging persistently:

```sql
SET SESSION log_statement = 'all'
SET log_statement = 'all'
SET LOCAL log_statement = 'all'
```

```sql
SET SESSION log_min_duration_statement = 0;
SET log_min_duration_statement = 0;
SET LOCAL log_min_duration_statement = 0;
```

Or:

```sql
RESET log_statement;
SET SESSION log_statement = 'none'
SET log_statement = 'none'
SET LOCAL log_statement = 'none'
```

```sql
RESET log_min_duration_statement;
SET SESSION log_min_duration_statement = -1;
SET log_min_duration_statement = -1;
SET LOCAL log_min_duration_statement = -1;
```

Answer (score 4):

When using containers it is easiest to add `-c log_statement=all` as a command-line argument.

Docker example:

```
docker run \
    --detach \
    --name mypostgres \
    --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword \
    postgres \
    -c log_statement=all
docker logs --follow mypostgres
```

Compose example:

```yaml
services:
  mypostgres:
    image: postgres:16.0
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
    command: "-c log_statement=all"
```

```
docker compose up --detach
docker compose logs --follow mypostgres
```

Answer (score 3):

You should also set this parameter to log every statement:

```
log_min_duration_statement = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Dynamically we can enable/disable the logging in 2 ways

1. Change the global variables in DB and reload the configuration
   a) Set log_statement = 'all'; or set log_min_duration_statement = 0;
   b) **select pg_reload_conf();**
2. From the Linux command line, edit the postgres configuration file, change the log related parameters
   log_min_duration_statement = 0
   log_statement = 'all'
   Reload the configuration file
   **su - postgres
   /usr/bin/pg_ctl reload**

In both these cases, we should not be doing a Postgres restart. We can dynamically enable/disable logging with configuration reload.

I hope this should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to set the `log_statement` in some postgres config file but in fact the file was not read by our postgres.

I confirmed that using the request :

```
select *
from pg_settings

[...]
log_statement   none # That was not the value i was expected for !!!
```

I use this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/41912295/2294168

```
command: postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgresql.conf
```