# Debugger database application and queries

Tags: debugging, postgresql, gdb

Can a debugger let me see the queries that the application does?
For example if I have a database application (written in C or in Java) that connect itself to postgresql, can gdb show me the statments inside the program?
Thank you

Comment: If you are looking to see a log of the queries, I would look at logging such as these: http://chrismiles.info/systemsadmin/databases/articles/viewing-current-postgresql-queries/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597516/app-to-monitor-postgresql-queries-in-real-time

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen Thank you. 
I've read it, but for me is a little different because I need to know the input parameters and the queries. So I've thought that maybe with the debugger I can see both of them (input and statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can gdb show me the statments inside the program?

Yes, but you'll need to find a place in the database server where that info is conveniently available, and set a breakpoint there.

It's possible that the client library turns the query and parameters into a packed structure of some sort before sending it to the server, and the info may *not* be conveniently available on the server side at all. But that's not very likely, as the server probably has ability to log the queries.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to check in the log db?

Comment: @DarkCoffee No, I don't mean that. I mean that you need to read the sources of your DB Server (if available) or reverse-engineer it (if sources are not available). Once you find the *place where statements being executed* are available (as function parameters, or values of variables), then set a breakpoint there and observe them.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am going to try it!