# Log all queries in the official Postgres docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a docker container based on Postgres's official docker image. I want to see the incoming queries when I look at the logs of the docker container using `docker logs -f`. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:11.1-alpine

COPY mock_data.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mock_data.sql

ENV PGDATA=/data
```

and this is the part of my docker-compose.yml file related to this service:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mock_data:
    image: mock_data
    container_name: mock_data
    ports:
         - 5434:5432/tcp
```

What is the eaasiest way to include the incoming queries in docker logs?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

If using Docker Compose, you can add this line to your **docker-compose.yaml** file:

```
command: ["postgres", "-c", "log_statement=all"]
```

and all your queries will be written into the container log file.

Answer (score 57):

Setting `log_destination` back to `stderr` did the trick for me without creating a new image:

```yaml
version: "2.2"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "log_statement=all", "-c", "log_destination=stderr"]
```

And then I was able to trace the statements using `docker-compose logs -f db`.
Should work with other versions too, but I only tested it with `postgres:12-alpine`.

Edit:
At the time of writing `log_destination` was not set to `stderr` in this image. This may have changed later on but this method still works for me even in newer images.

Comment: `log_destination=stderr` is not required as the default destination is `stderr`. Refer - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html

Comment: Did you test that with the `postgres:12-alpine` image? Because I remember doing that in dec. 2019 and it did not work that way for me...

Comment: Yes, I'm using `postgre:12.3-alpine`.

Comment: Had issues with `postgres:12.3` (PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1)). Upgrade to `postgres:12.4` did it for me.

Answer (score 39):

In case of running docker run directly from docker command, try follow command:

```bash
# single line to copy
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres -p 5432:5432 --name db postgres:10 postgres -c log_statement=all

# split to read. 
docker run -d \
    -e POSTGRES_USER=user \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass \
    -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    --name db \
    postgres:10 postgres \
    -c log_statement=all
```

The tailing part is overriding command as described here [overriding docker file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#overriding-dockerfile-image-defaults)

Good luck!

Comment: The `-c log_statement=all` worked perfectly for me. It did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 13):

Refer to [this](https://martianwabbit.com/2015/06/10/postgres-checking-queries-in-realtime.html), you should enable `logging_collector`, then you can see incoming queries in `log_directory`'s `log_filename`.

And to enable it in `docker logs`, you had to make some trick to make it, one solution is as follows:

**wrapper.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mkdir /logs
touch /logs/postgresql.log
chmod -R 777 /logs
tail -f /logs/* &
/docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

Above will use `tail` to monitor `/logs/postgresql.log` which will later be used by `postgresql`'s `logging_collector`, and show it `docker logs`.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM postgres:11.1-alpine
COPY wrapper.sh /
RUN chmod +x /wrapper.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/wrapper.sh"]
CMD ["postgres", "-c", "logging_collector=on", "-c", "log_directory=/logs", "-c", "log_filename=postgresql.log", "-c", "log_statement=all"]
```

Above will use customize `wrapper.sh`, it will first monitor the postgre log, print it, and then contiune to execute the default `docker-entrypoint.sh` to start postgresql server.

**After container start, show logs before incoming queries:**

```
orange@orange:~/abc$ docker build -t abc:1 .
orange@orange:~/abc$ docker run -idt abc:1
orange@orange:~/abc$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
c9112eb785e5        abc:1                  "/wrapper.sh postgre…"   2 seconds ago       Up 1 second         5432/tcp            loving_joliot
orange@orange:~/abc$ docker logs loving_joliot
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
......
2019-07-13 03:38:14.030 UTC [46] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-07-13 03:38:13 UTC
2019-07-13 03:38:14.034 UTC [10] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

**Simulate some incoming queries, and see logs again:**

```
orange@orange:~/abc$ docker exec -it -u postgres loving_joliot psql -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database;"
  datname
-----------
 postgres
 template1
 template0
(3 rows)
orange@orange:~/abc$ docker logs loving_joliot
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
......
2019-07-13 03:38:14.030 UTC [46] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-07-13 03:38:13 UTC
2019-07-13 03:38:14.034 UTC [10] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-07-13 03:41:22.859 UTC [62] LOG:  statement: SELECT datname FROM pg_database;
```

You can see above we simulate a sql execute `SELECT datname FROM pg_database;`, and in `docker logs` we could already see this sql.

Comment: what is this line in `wrapper.sh` file doing? `/docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"` because it is giving error `/docker-entrypoint.sh: not found`

Comment: This the default entrypoint in base image `postgres:11.1-alpine`: `docker run --rm postgres:11.1-alpine ls -alh /docker-entrypoint.sh`:  `lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          34 Feb  5  2019 /docker-entrypoint.sh -> usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`.  But this answer is ok just when the default postgres image don't have the `log_statement` feature (Which I don't know as that time); but if as the accepted answer mentioned, it already has embed feature for this log record, then use accept answer is enough.

Comment: i was able to get the real time logs without creating entrypoint script like you have..just needed to have `log_statement=all` and `pg_stat_statements.track = all` and that is all for postgres:13

Comment: YES< just like the accepted answer, please move step to that one.

Answer (score 11):

According to the documentation of the [official Postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) (section *Database Configuration*) you can either

- inject a custom configuration file (e.g. by means of adjusting the default configuration file) or
- start the container setting the configuration parameters required.

In the latter case simply start the container with

```sh
$ docker run -d --name some-postgres postgres -c log_statement=all
```

It makes use of [Overriding Dockerfile image defaults](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#overriding-dockerfile-image-defaults).

If you'd like to enable additional logging options check out the [Error reporting and Logging section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html) of the PostgreSQL docs.