# Finding all input parameter and the queries corresponding to those input parameter

Tags: postgresql, input-parameters

I have Postgresql DB on my pc and I'm trying to connect different database application to Postgresql but before that(An research issue), for each application, I need to see all the input parameter and all the queries corresponding to those input parameter that application can do.

How?

Comment: What application? If you need to do this without connecting it to a database then you'll need to look at the application itself.

Comment: did you have a look at [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgres-sql-queries)?

Comment: That's the point! I need to do it without connecting the application to database and consider when the application is not open source there is no access to the code. Since checking one by one each single  application is not feasible, I need a tool to do that for me. Obviously if exists. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the code of every application and see what calls are being made. In addition figure out all the parameter values that can be sent based on an almost infinite combination of characters and numbers the user can select from.

Or to remain sane turn on postgresql logging and let the users do their thing and analyse what calls are being made.

Comment: That's the point! I need to do it without connecting the application to database and consider when the application is not open source there is no access to the code. Since checking one by one each single  application is not feasible, I need a tool to do that for me. Obviously if exists. Thank you very much!

Comment: Let me know please if you any tool that can be helpful for me.

Comment: I don't believe there is a tool. You need to log your database as it's being used to do what you want.