# Detect when a row get deleted from PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, database, postgresql

Recently my team have get a situation in which some records in our shared test database disappear with no clear reason. Because it's a shared database (which is utilized by so many teams), so that we can't track down if it's a programming mistake or someone just run a bad sql script.

So that I'm looking for a way to notify (at database level) when a row of a specific table A get deleted. I have looked at the Postgres TRIGGER, but it failed to give me the specific sql that cause the deletion.

Is there anyway I can log the sql statement which cause the deletion of some rows in table A?

Comment: Look at the send/notify concept. That should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this to the actual postgres config files:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-logging.html

> log_statement (enum)
>
> ```
> Controls which SQL statements are logged. Valid values are none (off), ddl, mod, and all (all statements). ddl logs all data
> ```
>
> definition statements, such as CREATE, ALTER, and DROP statements. mod
>   logs all ddl statements, plus data-modifying statements such as
>   INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, and COPY FROM. PREPARE, EXECUTE, and
>   EXPLAIN ANALYZE statements are also logged if their contained command
>   is of an appropriate type. For clients using extended query protocol,
>   logging occurs when an Execute message is received, and values of the
>   Bind parameters are included (with any embedded single-quote marks
>   doubled).
>
> ```
> The default is none. Only superusers can change this setting.
> ```

You want either ddl or all to be the selection.  This is what you need to alter:
In your `data/postgresql.conf` file, change the `log_statement` setting to 'all'.  Further the following may also need to be validated:

```
1) make sure you have turned on the log_destination variable
2) make sure you turn on the logging_collector
3) also make sure that pg_log actually exists relative to your data directory, and that the postgres user can write to it.
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/722236/205426)

Comment: how forgetful I am! yes, it's the right way.. I think I would only need to put it "log_statement=mod' though...

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like [this](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger).

It allows you to create a special triggers for PostgreSQL tables, that log all the changes to the chosen tables.

This triggers can log the query, that cause the change (via `current_query()`).

Using this as a base you can add more fields/information to log.