# Heroku: Performing queries but no postgresql logs

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

When running a specific script that does some database queries on *Heroku* I'm getting an insufficient amount of information from my traceback to solve my problem.
(`django.db.utils.DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction`)

I would like to get more information about the problem from *postgresl*, I am able to access the logs of my local postgresql [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgres-sql-queries).

But on Heroku, running `heroku logs -p postgres` returns no information at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the starter-tier databases (dev, basic)? They don't offer logging. Also, I don't believe queries faster than 50ms are shown in the logs.

Comment: Yep, I'm using the free tier. Thanks for the info! Btw I can't get any scheduler logs either, although there is only a free tier for that. [`heroku logs --ps scheduler.1`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#inspecting-output) just returns no logs at all(while I should be producing logs). Is it because I only use one dyno for my app?

Comment: I have the same problem. No Postgres logs for the hobby tier, which includes the hobby-dev and hobby-basic plans. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans#hobby-tier