# Destination of PostgreSQL logs

Tags: postgresql

I tuned the server's variables almost like told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgres-sql-queries), but the log_destination is 'csvlog'.
After that in the data directory:

- the *.log file is empty.
- the file with same name but with .csv extension holds the logs from the server.

Explain me please -- this is correct behaviour?

If log_destination is 'csvlog' -- the output file will have the *.csv extension, rather  than .log?

What log_destination should be, to write logs in to the *.log file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if `log_destination` is `csvlog`, it will write to the csvlog, which should not be surprising.

If you want it to the regular logfile, set `log_destination=stderr`. You also need `logging_collector=on`, but you already have that if csv logging is working.