# Postgresql database got completely stuck in my busy transaction hours

Tags: performance, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1 with pgbouncer as a connection pool and my os is Linux5 x86_64 GNU/Linux. but my problem is its working fine after server start up and all my queries from application executes well but after few hours my data base become slow and after few minutes it got completely stuck in fact I can't see my activity using

```
select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

but after restarting my jboss and database it again works fine.And it happens in busy transaction time.
I think that my memory is not released from database after a query.

Comment: Anything in the log files? Try turning checkpoint logging on. PostgreSQL version, operating system, and PostgreSQL settings?

Comment: postgresql 9.1.7.12, RHEL 5.8 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: @ Craig Ringer will you be little specific sir about which parameter of checkpoint you are talking about i got checkpoint_segments,checkpoint_timeout,checkpoint_completion_target,checkpoint_warning parameters

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Logging_Checkpoints

Comment: thanks for the link but it didn't help any other idea....

Comment: So, *what* is happening? Is the machine running at 100% CPU, disk I/O, memory?

Comment: `avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           5.08    0.00    0.56    5.17    0.00   89.19`

`Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda             151.94       903.76      4536.37 2582075282 12960554560
sda1             41.34         8.20       949.40   23425178 2712453760
sda2             24.06         5.71       457.36   16320575 1306684800
sda3              0.03         1.20         1.20    3419552    3418576
sda4             86.50       888.65      3128.42 2538909553 8937997424`

Comment: cpu use 100% amd mem 21.94%

Comment: What is the process using the CPU? `$ top`

Comment: It is almost 99% above all the time..

Comment: `        PID   USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                    
        18517 enterpri  18   0 2520m 2.1g 2.0g R 21.9 13.3   2:23.96 postgres: enterprisedb etrans 127.0.0.1[32771] SELECT  ` one of my heavy process showing this status any help..

Comment: I could not able to solve my prob yet. please any one can help me on this..

Comment: Do you have query logging enabled? Please see the discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgres-sql-queries. Generating a log and feeding it to pgbadger will be very useful. Even if query logging is not enabled, pgbadger may provide some useful output. Also, I find output of htop more useful than that of top. htop uses - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/09/linux-htop-examples/

Comment: Do PostgreSQL have any query performance impact on the available space in my physical storage like hard disk

Comment: any more solutions???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research i have solve my problem by implementing `pgbounce` with its proper configuration ... and m very happy now with it.. Thanks all of my friend who have tried to add some value by commenting..

Comment: Can you share the experience with pgbounce?. How can I configure it with my existing application?