# Only log errors in Postgres (not all queries)

Tags: postgresql, error-logging, postgresql-9.4

I'm new to Postgres so can't seem to change the logging setting.

At the moment it logs ALL queries that are executed by any application. The app writes millions of queries a day so the log files get too big. I only need it to log any errors.

How can I change that in Postgres? I've installed it using Homebrew on Mac OS X.

Comment: Did your read this http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure in `postgresql.conf`(`data/postgresql.conf`) file

change the setting in `log_statement = 'all'` to get the desired value which is available in [When To Log](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHEN)

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries) SO question for more info.

Comment: My configuration already seems to be set to `log_statement='none'` yet is still logging all queries.

Comment: just go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries you'll get more details about logging

Answer (score 0):

@jacob You can restart the postgresql service by sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart or sudo service postgresql restart.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Sorry @ρяσѕρєяK I am new to here. So i did't have a permission to add a comments in others answer.