# Customize the configuration of the official PostgreSQL docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, postgresql-9.4

I am using the official postgresql docker image (version 9.4). I have extended the Dockerfile, so I can alter the settings in the postgresql.conf etc, using a bash script. **It successfully adds and runs the script on entrypoint, for a single sed command**. But when I put 2 or more sed commands, I get the following error:

> /docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/config.sh
>   : No such file or directoryread
>   /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf

I am trying on Windows 10, in combination with Vagrant and VirtualBox, using NFS file system on shared folders, via the vagrant-winnfsd plugin.

Why is this happening? How can I alter my bash script in order to work with more configuration settings? Is there a better way?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:9.4

RUN echo "Europe/Athens" > /etc/timezone \
 && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

RUN localedef -i el_GR -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias el_GR.UTF-8

ADD config.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN chmod 755 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/config.sh

VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]
```

config.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i -e"s/^#logging_collector = off.*$/logging_collector = on/" /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
sed -i -e"s/^max_connections = 100.*$/max_connections = 1000/" /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

database.yml

```
postgres:
    container_name: postgres-9.4
    image: ***/postgres-9.4
    volumes_from:
      - postgres_data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=database
      - USERMAP_UID=999
      - USERMAP_GID=999

postgres_data:
    container_name: postgres_data
    image: ***/postgres-9.4
    volumes:
      - ./services/postgres:/etc/postgresql
      - ./services/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql
      - ./services/postgres/logs:/var/log/postgresql
    command: "true"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the configuration file of the official PostgreSQL docker image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848670/how-to-customize-the-configuration-file-of-the-official-postgresql-docker-image)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using a `RUN` statement to execute your bash script or just run sed directly with both commands combined with a semicolon:

```
RUN sed -i -e 's/^#\(logging_collector = \).*/\1on/; s/^\(max_connections = \).*/\11000/' \
    /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

A more scalable solution would be to put the sed program in an external file, then use these statements:

```
ADD postgres-edit.sed /var/local
RUN sed -i -f /var/local/postgres-edit.sed /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

postgres-edit.sed:

```
# sed script to edit postgresql configuration

s/^#\(logging_collector = \).*/\1on/
s/^\(max_connections = \).*/\11000/
```

Comment: If I use this inside my Dockerfile, it would not work.

Comment: You said that a single sed command works. If you're editting a single file, there's no need to call sed more than once. Just join the commands with semi colons as I've done. Or put them in a file one command per line with no semi colons and call it with: `sed -i -f postgresql-edit.sed /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf`.

Comment: You definitely got me to the right path. I put all my configs inside the postgresql-edit.sed. But still, I used the config.sh to execute the sed -i -f command. Getting this done via the Dockerfile with ADD sed -i -f, simply does not work. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a duplicate of [How to customize the configuration file of the official PostgreSQL docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848670).

Copy-paste of my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40598124/385548.

---

## Inject custom postgresql.conf into postgres Docker container

The default `postgresql.conf` file lives within the `PGDATA` dir (`/var/lib/postgresql/data`), which makes things more complicated especially when running postgres container for the first time, since the `docker-entrypoint.sh` wrapper invokes the `initdb` step for `PGDATA` dir initialization.

To customize PostgreSQL configuration in Docker consistently, I suggest using `config_file` postgres option together with Docker volumes like this:

### Production database (PGDATA dir as Persistent Volume)

```
docker run -d \
-v $CUSTOM_CONFIG:/etc/postgresql.conf \
-v $CUSTOM_DATADIR:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
-e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
-p 5432:5432 \
--name postgres \
postgres:9.6 postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgresql.conf
```

### Testing database (PGDATA dir will be discarded after `docker rm`)

```
docker run -d \
-v $CUSTOM_CONFIG:/etc/postgresql.conf \
-e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
--name postgres \
postgres:9.6 postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgresql.conf
```

---

#### Debugging

1. Remove the `-d` (detach option) from `docker run` command to see the server logs directly.
2. Connect to the postgres server with psql client and query the configuration:

   ```
   docker run -it --rm --link postgres:postgres postgres:9.6 sh -c 'exec psql -h $POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR -p $POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT -U postgres'

   psql (9.6.0)
   Type "help" for help.

   postgres=# SHOW all;
   ```