# How can I modify configuration file variables of the PostgreSQL service in GitLab CI?

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to modify the `shared_buffers` value of the Postgres service.  I am using my own server for the GitLab runner, but am using the public GitLab instance; so I can change the runner configuration, but not the configuration of GitLab itself.   As GitLab CI uses the standard upstream Docker `postgres` service, documented here, it seems like it might be possible to copy shell scripts into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and do initialization here.  However I can't find any way to access paths inside the container from `gitlab-ci.yml`.

My question is similar to the following:
[How to customize the configuration file of the official PostgreSQL docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848670/how-to-customize-the-configuration-file-of-the-official-postgresql-docker-image)  Except that because GitLab CI wraps the Docker initialization in its own [interface](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/), the methods shown that use `Dockerfile` changes can't be obviously translated into a form that works with `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

Any method based on creating your own image with a customized Dockerfile that uses `postgres` image as a base can work perfectly fine for you. Simply create a new image and post it to a registry - this can be either the Docker Hub or your own [private registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) running on the same server as the runner.

In your `.gitlab-ci.yml` you would then reference that image of yours. In case of Docker Hub:

```
image: amoe/postgres
```

...or in case of a private registry on the same host as the runner:

```
image: localhost:5000/amoe-postgres
```