# How to increase max_connection in the official PostgreSQL Docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker, sed

### Problem

I have too many connection open using the default docker `postgresql` configuration

- https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

### Goal

I want to extend `max_connection` without using a volume for mounting the configuration (I need this to be available by default for my CI environment).

I have tried to use `sed` to edit the configuration but this has no effect.

What is the recommended way of overriding default configuration of postgresql docker official image?

Comment: This might help: [How to customize the configuration file of the official PostgreSQL Docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30848670/3776858)

Comment: Please see example in the documentation : https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#database-configuration

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It is as simple as (you just override the default `CMD` with `postgres -N 500`):

```
docker run -d --name db postgres:10 postgres -N 500
```

You can check it using:

```
docker run -it --rm --link db:db postgres psql -h db -U postgres

show max_connections;

max_connections 
-----------------
500
(1 row)
```

Comment: + -B 4096MB # accompanying shared buffers

Answer (score 109):

run this docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.3-alpine
    command: -c 'max_connections=200'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: pgdb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
    - 5432:5432/tcp
```

Comment: You can actually omit the `postgres` part from `command:` as the official image will [automatically forward](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#database-configuration) any command options to `postgres`.

"The entrypoint script is made so that any options passed to the docker command will be passed along to the postgres server daemon."

Answer (score 22):

The official image provides a way to run arbitrary SQL and shell scripts after the DB is initialized by putting them into the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory. This script:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET max_connections = 500;
```

will let us change the maximum connection limit. Note that the postgres server will be restarted after the initializing scripts are run, so even settings like `max_connections` that require a restart will go into effect when your container starts for the first time.

How you attach this script to the docker container depends on how you are starting it:

### Docker

Save the SQL script to a file `max_conns.sql`, then use it as a volume:

```
docker run -it -v $PWD/max_conns.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/max_conns.sql postgres
```

### Docker Compose

With docker compose, save the SQL script to a file `max_conns.sql` next to your `docker-compose.yaml`, and than reference it:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - ./max_conns.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/max_conns.sql
```

### Kubernetes

With kubernetes, you will need to create a configmap for the script:

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata:
  name: max-conns
data:
  max_conns.sql: "ALTER SYSTEM SET max_connections = 500;"
```

And then use it with a container:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-example
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:latest
          volumeMounts:
          - name: max-conns
            mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      volumes:
        - name: max-conns
          configMap:
            name: max-conns
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `TestContainers` do this before starting the container

```
  postgreSQLContainer.setCommand("postgres", "-c", "max_connections=20000");
  postgreSQLContainer.start();
```

From Google, Max value allowed 262143 min 1 and default 100

Answer (score 3):

For containers/pods deployed on Kubernetes, `max_connections` can be updated by adding arguments to the entry point command from the container spec:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: postgres1
    image: postgres:15
    args: ["-c", "max_connections=1000"]
```

For containers deployed in the docker engine using `docker run`, you can pass `-c max_connections=1000`.

Ref: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Answer (score 1):

You need to develop a init script. Accept max connections value from environment variable and update it during start up from init script. Finally launch postgreSQL service

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time in this issue and the simplest way to resolve this is, you can add max_connections in your values.yaml file straight away. You can specify extended configuration parameters, this option will override the conf file.

For instance;
extendedConfiguration: "max_connections = 500"

Comment: Dude you saved my sanity! I can't thank you enough!