# How to increase max_connection in github action Postgres

Tags: postgresql, github-actions

I want to increase `max_connections` in github action Postgres service. [Official document](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-postgresql-service-containers) doesn't mention how to do so. Is there some clever hacks?

I tried [this SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252026/how-to-increase-max-connection-in-the-official-postgresql-docker-image), which don't seem to work in github action environment.

Comment: What is the default value of `max_connections` in github action postgres service?

Answer (score 0):

There is a straightforward way to do it, but you can achieve it by installing the pg client and configuration the container when the service starts. The exact steps are documented in this [blog post](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2022/05/12/github-actions-postgresql-increase-max-connections-and-shared-buffers/).

The relevant code:

```
steps:
  - name: Install postgresql-client
    run: |
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install --yes postgresql-client

  - name: Connect to PostgreSQL with CLI
    run: psql -c 'SELECT VERSION();'

  - name: Show PostgreSQL config file
    run: psql -c 'SHOW config_file;'

  - name: Alter max connections
    run: |
      docker exec -i postgres bash << EOF
        sed -i -e 's/max_connections = 100/max_connections = 1000/' /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
        sed -i -e 's/shared_buffers = 128MB/shared_buffers = 2GB/' /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
      EOF
      docker restart --time 0 postgres
      sleep 5

  - name: Show max connections
    run: psql -c 'SHOW max_connections;'
```

As there isn't an option to set a custom command for Docker services, this remains the most straightforward way of doing it.