# How to update max_connections in postgresql deployed on Kubernetes pod

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I want to update the max_connection count in /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/postgresql.conf file, postgresql database is deployed in the form of pod. There is no vim present inside pod to update the file, nor I could modify the Dockerfile to install vim, as I don't have access for that. Also I have tried adding the args and command in the deployment.yaml file

```
containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:latest
          args: ["-c", "max_connections=500"]
```

still no luck for it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `sed` to edit this file?
2. Some helpfull options [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252026/how-to-increase-max-connection-in-the-official-postgresql-docker-image)

Comment: sed sample: `sed -i "s/max_connections = .*/max_connections = 500/i" /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/postgresql.conf`

Comment: I have updated the file now, but it requires to restart postgres, when trying to restart postgres it gives below error. warn] No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster" ... (warning)

Comment: You must use pg_ctl command instead pg_ctlcluster. Ex.: 

`su - postgres -c "$(find /usr/lib/ -name pg_ctl) restart -D /var/lib/postgresql/data/"`

`-D` parameter must indicate the local data directory on pod, and the user to execute must be postgres

Answer (score 0):

Just increasing `max_connections` is bad idea. You need to increase `shared_buffers` and `kernel.shmmax` as well.

Kindly refer to this SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584211/12014434) for more information.

Comment: got your point, but since I have deployed postgres on Kubernetes pod not sure how to update the max_connections and shared_buffer, since vim tool is not present inside the pod to edit the conf file. I am using the official postgres image postgres:13.4, and here there is no env variable option for max_connection or shared buffer