# Link two volumes, container not start

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis

I try to deploy a container docker-postgis 11 with this command :

It's possible to link two volumes ? or what it's the best way to modify the conf files ( postgresql -pg_hba.conf)
Thank you

> docker run -d \
>   -v $HOME/postgres_data/data:/var/lib/postgresql \
>   -v $HOME/postgres_data/conf:/etc/postgresql/11/main  \
>   -p 5433:5432 \
>   --name=testpostgis \
>   -e POSTGRES_USER="gis" \
>   -e POSTGRES_PASS="gis" \
>   -e POSTGRES_DBNAME="gis" \
>   -d kartoza/postgis:11.0-2.5

But when i link the second volume , the container not restart
My goal it' have the possiblility to modify the conf file

Comment: have a look at this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848670/how-to-customize-the-configuration-file-of-the-official-postgresql-docker-image

Answer (score 1):

The rigth way to modify the inside configuration of a base image is building it from Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM kartoza/postgis:11.0-2.5

COPY $HOME/postgres_data/conf /etc/postgresql/11/main

ENTRYPOINT /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Then run:

```
docker run -d \
-v $HOME/postgres_data/data:/var/lib/postgresql \
-p 5433:5432 \
--name=testpostgis \
-e POSTGRES_USER="gis" \
-e POSTGRES_PASS="gis" \
-e POSTGRES_DBNAME="gis" \
-d kartoza/postgis:11.0-2.5
```