# Add custom config location to Docker Postgres image preserving its access parameters

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have written a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM postgres:11.2-alpine
ADD ./db/postgresql.conf /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
CMD ["-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf"]
```

It just adds custom config location to a generic Postgres image.

Now I have the following `docker-compose` service description

```
db:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./db/Dockerfile
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD passwordhere
    POSTGRES_USER: user
    POSTGRES_DB: db_name
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
  volumes:
    - ./run/db-data:/var/lib/db/data
```

The problem is I can no longer remotely connect to DB using these credentials if I add this Config option. Without that `CMD` line it works just fine.

If I prepend `"postgres"` in `CMD` it has the same effect due to the underlying script prepending it itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided all the files are where they need to be, I believe the only problem with your setup is that you've omitted an actual executable from the `CMD` -- specifying just the option. You need to actually run postgres:

```
CMD ["postgres", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf"]
```

That should work!

## EDIT in response to OP's first comment below

First, I did confirm that behavior doesn't change whether "postgres" is in the `CMD` or not. It's exactly as you said. Onward!

Then I thought there must be a problem with the particular `postgresql.conf` in use. If we could just figure out what the default file is.. turns out we can!

### How to get the existing postgres.conf out of the postgres image

#### 1. Create `docker-compose.yml` with the following contents:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11.2-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=passwordhere
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_DB=db_name
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./run/db-data:/var/lib/db/data
```

#### 2. Spin up the service using

```
$ docker-compose run --rm --name=postgres db
```

#### 3. In another terminal get the location of the file used in this release:

```
$ docker exec -it postgres psql --dbname=db_name --username=user --command="SHOW config_file"
               config_file
------------------------------------------
 /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
(1 row)
```

#### 4. View the contents of default postgresql.conf

```
$ docker exec -it postgres cat /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

#### 5. Replace local config file

Now all we have to do is replace the local config file `./db/postgresql.conf` with the contents of the known-working-state config and modify it as necessary.

### Database objects are only created once!

Database objects are only created once by the postgres container ([source](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/41#issuecomment-167603905)). So when developing the database parameters we have to remove them to make sure we're in a clean state.

Here's a **nuclear (be careful!)** option to
(1) remove all exited Docker containers, and then
(2) remove all Docker volumes not attached to containers:

```
$ docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) -f && docker volume prune -f
```

So now we can be sure to start from a clean state!

### Final setup

Let's bring our Dockerfile back into the picture (just like you have in the question).

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./db/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=passwordhere
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_DB=db_name
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./run/db-data:/var/lib/db/data
```

#### Connect to the db

Now all we have to do is build from a clean state.

```
# ensure all volumes are deleted (see above)
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose run --rm --name=postgres db
```

We can now (still) connect to the database:

```
$ docker exec -it postgres psql --dbname=db_name --username=user --command="SELECT COUNT(1) FROM pg_database WHERE datname='db_name'"
```

Finally, we can edit the `postgres.conf` from a known working state.

Comment: Like I said in other comment, it produces the same effect.

Comment: I think this should work @Gherman. That was quite a rabbit hole. Hope that helps!

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. I want to change config file location. I already know where the file is. The location must be changed. That's because I don't want it within the volume accessible outside container.

Comment: If you follow the directions exactly, at the end you can re-run the `docker .. SHOW config_file` command (provided earlier in the answer); it outputs `/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf`, which is specified in your Dockerfile.

Comment: The answer does not include where you change `CMD`, though it is included in my question. That's why I misunderstood. Yes, this is a working solution. In short I should have added my setiings on top of existing ones. Should have guessed.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this other discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848670/how-to-customize-the-configuration-file-of-the-official-postgresql-docker-image/41912295), your `CMD` command only has arguments and is missing a command.  Try:

```
CMD ["postgres", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf"]
```

Comment: This has exactly the same effect. Actually the underlying shell-script in `ENTRYPOINT` prepends `postgres` if it's absent. In fact I can access db from inside the container but not outside. And `SHOW config_file;` returns the correct config.

Comment: can you paste the contents of your custom `postgresql.conf` somewhere? What is the `listen_addresses` setting?