# Kubernetes Postgres Bus error (core dumped)

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, kubectl, pgadmin

I am deploying pgadmin and postgres on kubernetes. When i look at deployments I see that 2 deployments are not ready. When I look at logs of Pgadmin, I see that it gives error as it can not connect to postgres. I use configmap to connect pgadmin to postgres. When I look at logs of postgres I see error.

Logs:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 20
selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
creating configuration files ... ok
Bus error (core dumped)
child process exited with exit code 135
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
running bootstrap script ...
```

yaml file:

```
#configmap
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-configmap
data:
  db_url: postgres-service
---
#postgres
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:13.3
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: postgres-secret
              key: postgres-password 
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgres
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
---
#pgadmin
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pgadmin-deployment
  labels:
    app: pgadmin
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pgadmin
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pgadmin
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pgadmin
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        ports:
        - containerPort: 49762
        env:
        - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL
          value: email@email.com
        - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name: PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: postgres-configmap
              key: db_url
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pgadmin-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: pgadmin
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 49762
      targetPort: 49762
      nodePort: 30001
```

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/451#issuecomment-447472044

Comment: @Ashok how can i edit /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample file while postgres runs inside container?

Comment: You can put your custom `postgresql.conf` in a temporary file inside the container, and overwrite the default configuration at runtime.

Comment: Do u think i can do it with env variables? @Ashok

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848670/how-to-customize-the-configuration-file-of-the-official-postgresql-docker-image

Comment: @Ashok thanks but i doesn't cover kubernetes.

Comment: Try to Keep a dummy entry point script and then spin up the container or else try to copy the file to the container

Comment: @Ashok i use default postgres image how can i use entrypoint script?

Comment: BTW I use "play with kubernetes" website.

Comment: @Ashok thanks for your help

Comment: @Ashok, Could you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: @name46327 has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 3):

After analysing the comments it looks like below resources have been helpful to solve this problem:

1. [How to customize the configuration file of the official PostgreSQL Docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848670/how-to-customize-the-configuration-file-of-the-official-postgresql-docker-image)
2. https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/451#issuecomment-447472044

To sum up, editing `/usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample` file while postgres runs inside a container can be done by putting a custom `postgresql.conf` in a temporary file inside the container and overwriting the default configuration at runtime as described [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/451#issuecomment-447472044). Also, keeping a dummy entry point script using "play with kubernetes" [websites](https://www.google.com/search?q=play%20with%20kubernetes&rlz=1CAZVTZ_enPL954PL954&ei=pd_VYKWEBeiOrwTs8JjwDg&oq=play%20with%20kubernetes&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEEMyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgcIABBHELADSgQIQRgAULv6OVi7-jlgwvs5aAJwAngAgAFziAHTAZIBAzEuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjl6rKe97LxAhVox4sKHWw4Bu4Q4dUDCA4&uact=5) and then spinning up the container or trying to copy the file to the container might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

After having the problem myself it seems that it strongly relates to `huge_pages` being activated in the underlying OS in `sysctl.conf`.

The relationship of the error to `huge_pages` was not clear for me from skimming through the previous answer, hence this is a small write-up to make it clearer and directly summarize possible solutions.

### Possible solutions for k8s:

1. Disable `huge_pages` in the OS with setting `vm.nr_hugepages = 0` in `sysctl.conf`, taken from [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/15419#issuecomment-1463301139). Please note that a restart might be necessary for the changes to take effect.
2. Disable `huge_pages` in *postgresql* by modifying postgresql config with the option `huge_pages = off`, taken from [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/451#issuecomment-871109581).

### Solution for bitnami helm chart:

In case you run into this problem while trying to deploy *postgresql* with `bitnami` charts. The `postgresql.conf.sample` can't be modified directly due to permission problems.
But [this](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/7901#issuecomment-1505150755) github thread provides an example helm config to get the bitnami chart working.

```yaml
primary:
  extendedConfiguration: |-
    huge_pages = off
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: pg-sample-config
      mountPath: /opt/bitnami/postgresql/share/postgresql.conf.sample
      subPath: postgresql.conf.sample
  extraVolumes:
    - configMap:
        name: pg-sample-config
      name:  pg-sample-config
extraDeploy:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: pg-sample-config
    data:
      postgresql.conf.sample: |-
        huge_pages = off
```