# Docker denied for /bin/sh

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, fedora

I'm using the following Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml.

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG RUST_BUILDER_IMAGE=clux/muslrust:1.67.0

FROM $RUST_BUILDER_IMAGE as chef
USER root
RUN cargo install cargo-chef
WORKDIR /app

# Cargo chef plan
FROM chef as planner
ENV RUSTFLAGS="--cfg tokio_unstable"

# Copy dirs
COPY . .

RUN cargo chef prepare --recipe-path recipe.json

FROM chef as builder
ARG CARGO_BUILD_TARGET=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
ARG RUSTRELEASEDIR="debug"
ENV RUSTFLAGS="--cfg tokio_unstable"

COPY --from=planner /app/recipe.json ./recipe.json
RUN cargo chef cook --recipe-path recipe.json --target ${CARGO_BUILD_TARGET}

# Copy the rest of the dirs
COPY . .

# Build the project
RUN echo "pub const VERSION: &str = \"$(git describe --tag)\";" > "crates/utils/src/version.rs"
RUN cargo build --target ${CARGO_BUILD_TARGET}

RUN cp ./target/$CARGO_BUILD_TARGET/$RUSTRELEASEDIR/lemmy_server /app/lemmy_server

# The alpine runner
FROM alpine:3 as lemmy

# Install libpq for postgres
RUN apk add libpq

# Copy resources
COPY --from=builder /app/lemmy_server /app/lemmy

EXPOSE 8536
CMD ["/app/lemmy"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.3"

networks:
  # communication to web and clients
  lemmyexternalproxy:
  # communication between lemmy services
  lemmyinternal:
    driver: bridge
    internal: true

services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:1-alpine
    networks:
      - lemmyinternal
      - lemmyexternalproxy
    ports:
    # actual and only port facing any connection from outside 
      - "1236:1236"
      - "8536:8536"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - pictrs
      - lemmy-ui

  lemmy:
    # image: dessalines/lemmy:dev
    # use this to build your local lemmy server image for development
    # run docker compose up --build
    build: 
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
    # this hostname is used in nginx reverse proxy and also for lemmy ui to connect to the backend, do not change
    hostname: lemmy
    networks:
      - lemmyinternal
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RUST_LOG="warn,lemmy_server=debug,lemmy_api=debug,lemmy_api_common=debug,lemmy_api_crud=debug,lemmy_apub=debug,lemmy_db_schema=debug,lemmy_db_views=debug,lemmy_db_views_actor=debug,lemmy_db_views_moderator=debug,lemmy_routes=debug,lemmy_utils=debug,lemmy_websocket=debug"
      - RUST_BACKTRACE=full
    volumes:
      - ./lemmy.hjson:/config/config.hjson
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - pictrs

  lemmy-ui:
    image: dessalines/lemmy-ui:0.17.2
    # use this to build your local lemmy ui image for development
    # run docker compose up --build
    # assuming lemmy-ui is cloned besides lemmy directory
    # build: 
    #  context: ../../../lemmy-ui
    #  dockerfile: dev.dockerfile
    networks:
      - lemmyinternal
    environment:
      # this needs to match the hostname defined in the lemmy service
      - LEMMY_UI_LEMMY_INTERNAL_HOST=lemmy:8536
      # set the outside hostname here
      - LEMMY_UI_LEMMY_EXTERNAL_HOST=localhost:1236
      - LEMMY_HTTPS=false
      - LEMMY_UI_DEBUG=true
    depends_on:
      - lemmy
    restart: always

  pictrs:
    image: asonix/pictrs:0.3.1
    # this needs to match the pictrs url in lemmy.hjson
    hostname: pictrs
    # we can set options to pictrs like this, here we set max. image size and forced format for conversion
    # entrypoint: /sbin/tini -- /usr/local/bin/pict-rs -p /mnt -m 4 --image-format webp
    networks:
      - lemmyinternal
    environment:
      - PICTRS_OPENTELEMETRY_URL=http://otel:4137
      - PICTRS__API_KEY=API_KEY
      - RUST_LOG=debug
      - RUST_BACKTRACE=full
    user: 991:991
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/pictrs:/mnt
    restart: always

  postgres:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    # this needs to match the database host in lemmy.hson
    # Tune your settings via
    # https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/
    # You can use this technique to add them here
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/30850095/1655478
    hostname: postgres
    command: [
      "postgres",
      "-c", "session_preload_libraries=auto_explain",
      "-c", "auto_explain.log_min_duration=5ms",
      "-c", "auto_explain.log_analyze=true",
      "-c", "track_activity_query_size=1048576"
    ]
    networks:
      - lemmyinternal
    # adding the external facing network to allow direct db access for devs
      - lemmyexternalproxy
    ports:
    # use a different port so it doesnt conflict with potential postgres db running on the host
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=lemmy
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=lemmy
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always

  otel:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector:latest
    command: --config otel-local-config.yaml
    networks:
      - lemmyinternal
      - lemmyexternalproxy
    ports:
      - "4317:4317"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./otel.yml
        target: /otel-local-config.yaml
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - jaeger
  
  jaeger:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:1
    networks:
      - lemmyinternal
      - lemmyexternalproxy
    ports:
      - "14250:14250"
      # To view traces, visit http://localhost:16686
      - "16686:16686"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

When I try running the command `sudo docker-compose up -d --build` I get the following error:

```
Building lemmy
[+] Building 0.7s (9/19)                                                                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 97B                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 93B                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/clux/muslrust:1.67.0                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [chef 1/3] FROM docker.io/clux/muslrust:1.67.0                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [lemmy 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                              0.2s
 => => transferring context: 147.86kB                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => ERROR [lemmy 2/3] RUN apk add libpq                                                                                                                                                        0.6s
 => ERROR [chef 2/3] RUN cargo install cargo-chef                                                                                                                                              0.6s
------                                                                                                                                                                                              
 > [lemmy 2/3] RUN apk add libpq:
#6 0.533 exec /bin/sh: permission denied
------
------
 > [chef 2/3] RUN cargo install cargo-chef:
#8 0.519 exec /bin/sh: permission denied
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add libpq]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'lemmy' failed to build : Build failed
```

It only gives me this error when I try running the command on my computer that uses Fedora 37. I tried this on another computer that has Windows 11 as its OS and it worked as expected.

**Edit**: Per Matt Blaha's request, I ran `sudo ausearch -m AVC`. I got the following output:

```
----
time->Mon Mar 13 06:21:58 2023
type=AVC msg=audit(1678702918.336:74574): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=1317985 comm="pict-rs" name="pictrs" dev="sda2" ino=3899807 scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c100,c560 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
----
time->Mon Mar 13 06:22:08 2023
type=AVC msg=audit(1678702928.673:74597): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1318095 comm="lemmy" name="lemmy.hjson" dev="sda2" ino=3899212 scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c51,c467 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
----
time->Mon Mar 13 06:22:35 2023
type=AVC msg=audit(1678702955.849:74631): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1318336 comm="nginx" name="nginx.conf" dev="sda2" ino=3899213 scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c369,c816 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
----
time->Mon Mar 13 06:22:39 2023
type=AVC msg=audit(1678702959.676:74663): avc:  denied  { setattr } for  pid=1318675 comm="chmod" name="postgres" dev="sda2" ino=3902050 scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c5,c553 tcontext=system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
----
time->Mon Mar 13 06:22:39 2023
type=AVC msg=audit(1678702959.679:74664): avc:  denied  { setattr } for  pid=1318679 comm="chown" name="postgres" dev="sda2" ino=3902050 scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c5,c553 tcontext=system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
----
time->Mon Mar 13 06:22:54 2023
type=AVC msg=audit(1678702974.663:74696): avc:  denied  { entrypoint } for  pid=1319016 comm="runc:[2:INIT]" path="/bin/busybox" dev="sda2" ino=264 scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c147,c401 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
----
time->Mon Mar 13 06:22:54 2023
type=AVC msg=audit(1678702974.665:74697): avc:  denied  { entrypoint } for  pid=1319017 comm="runc:[2:INIT]" path="/usr/bin/dash" dev="sda2" ino=498 scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c15,c360 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Comment: I'd suspect SELinux on Fedora. Are you getting any alerts? sudo ausearch -m AVC ?

Comment: Updated OP to include output from that command.

Comment: Was having the same. Fixed it running "sudo setenforce 0"
Not sure it's the safest, but will do for now.

Reference:
https://nanxiao.me/en/selinux-cause-permission-denied-issue-in-using-docker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, your problem is that SELinux is blocking the access. (Which is good! resist the urge to disable SELinux.)

docker-compose can relabel the files for you.

For files being denied, when you define a volume just add the z or Z flag as appropriate.

z is for files to be shared between containers, Z is for files to be used by only one container.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-the-selinux-label

Do note this important warning:

"This affects the file or directory on the host machine itself and can have consequences outside of the scope of Docker."

It looks like all of your files are in a home folder and labeled correctly that way. You may just have to use restorecon on them if anything breaks, but be aware.

So where you have:

```
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

try:

```
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
```

Comment: Adding the Z flag to the volumes didn't make any difference. I tried @vilma's approach and it worked, however as you said I should resist the urge to turn off SELinux.

Comment: Do the logs change at least? You should be removing at least some of those deny messages just by labeling the volumes.

Comment: Oh I see, that link I included notes there's a long standing bug when using services, I switched to using podman on Fedora several years ago . . . you might try "chcon -t container_file_t" on the offending files to do what Z should do manually. Look at man chcon and restorecon for lots of details.

Comment: I'll try that when I'm able to use that machine again and let you know the results.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to mark this question as answered. I put off fixing it for awhile. It's still not working as I expect it to, however it seems to be for reasons that have nothing to do with SELinux. I'm marking your answer as accepted.