# What's the difference between select_related and prefetch_related in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-select-related, django-prefetch-related

In Django doc:

> [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) "follows" foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query.
>
> [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the "joining" in Python.

What does it mean by "doing the joining in python"? Can someone illustrate with an example?

My understanding is that for foreign key relationship, use `select_related`; and for M2M relationship, use `prefetch_related`. Is this correct?

Comment: Performing the join in python means that the join will not happen in the database. With a select_related, your join happens in the database and you only suffer one database query. With prefetch_related, you will be executing two queries and then the results will be 'joined' by the ORM so you can still type object.related_set

Comment: As a footnote, Timmy O'Mahony can also explain their differences using database hits: [link](https://timmyomahony.com/blog/misconceptions-select_related-in-django/)

Comment: This may help you https://learnbatta.com/blog/working-with-select_related-in-django-89/

Comment: Using select_for_update with select_related will acquire locks on the related objects.
The same will not happen if used with prefetch_related. Atleast this has been the behaviour till Django 1.11.29

Answer (score 733, accepted):

Your understanding is **mostly** correct:

- `select_related`: when the object that you're going to be selecting is a single object, so `OneToOneField` or a `ForeignKey`
- `prefetch_related`: when you're going to get a "set" of things, so `ManyToManyField`s as you stated or reverse `ForeignKey`s.

Just to clarify what I mean by reverse `ForeignKey`s, here's an example:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelB(models.Model):
    a = ForeignKey(ModelA)

# Forward ForeignKey relationship
ModelB.objects.select_related('a').all()

# Reverse ForeignKey relationship
ModelA.objects.prefetch_related('modelb_set').all()
```

The difference is that:

- `select_related` does an SQL join and therefore gets the results back as part of the table from the SQL server
- `prefetch_related` on the other hand executes another query and therefore reduces the redundant columns in the original object (`ModelA` in the above example)

You may use `prefetch_related` for anything that you can use `select_related` for.

The tradeoffs are that `prefetch_related` has to create and send a list of IDs to select back to the server, this can take a while. I'm not sure if there's a nice way of doing this in a transaction, but my understanding is that Django always just sends a list and says SELECT ... WHERE pk IN (...,...,...) basically. In this case if the prefetched data is sparse (let's say U.S. State objects linked to people's addresses) this can be very good, however if it's closer to one-to-one, this can waste a lot of communications. If in doubt, try both and see which performs better.

Everything discussed above is basically about the communications with the database. On the Python side however `prefetch_related` has the extra benefit that a single object is used to represent each object in the database. With `select_related` duplicate objects will be created in Python for each "parent" object. Since objects in Python have a decent bit of memory overhead this can also be a consideration.

Comment: what is faster though?

Comment: `select_related` is one query while `prefetch_related` is two, so the former is faster. But `select_related` won't help you for `ManyToManyField`'s

Comment: @eladsilver Sorry for the slow reply. It actually depends. `select_related` uses a JOIN in the SQL whereas `prefetch_related` run the query on the first model, collects all the IDs it needs to prefetch and then runs a query with an IN clause in the WHERE with all the IDs that it needs. If you have say 3-5 models using the same foreign key, `select_related` will almost certainly be better. If you have 100s or 1000s of models using the same foreign key, `prefetch_related` could actually be better. In between you'll have to test and see what happens.

Comment: I would dispute your comment about prefetch related "generally doesn't make much sense". That's true for FK fields marked unique, but anywhere where multiple rows have the same FK value (author, user, category, city etc etc) prefetch cuts down bandwidth between Django and the DB but not duplicating rows. It also generally uses less memory on the DB. Either of these is often more important than the overhead of a single extra query. Given this is the top answer on a reasonably popular question I think that should be noted in the answer.

Comment: @GordonWrigley Yeah, it's been a while since I wrote that, so I went back and clarified a bit. I'm not sure I agree with the "uses less memory on the DB" bit, but yes to everything. And it can sure use less memory on the Python side.

Comment: @chrisFrisina I have no idea what that edit was supposed to be. It looks like you're trying to turn my comments into quotes. If you can explain your change I'd be happy to put it back.

Comment: I was visually clarifying via blocks.   The markup names these `quotes` as you are referring to them, however, it appears this question/answer is being used as a reference given its high traffic count, so I was attempting to make it easier to read visually from a concatenated paragraph as it was originally written.    Whichever way you want to do it is fine

Comment: @CrazyCasta what is `modelb_set` here?

Comment: Given an instance of `ModelA`, `modelb_set` on that instance of `ModelA` is an iterable of `ModelB` instances that have as value `a` the instance of `ModelA` that you are looking at `modelb_set` for. It's saying "give me all objects of `ModelB` that have as value `a` this thing that I'm using `modelb_set` on".

Answer (score 44):

Gone through the already posted answers. Just thought it would be better if I add an answer with actual example.

Let' say you have 3 Django models which are related.

```
class M1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class M2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    select_relation = models.ForeignKey(M1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prefetch_relation = models.ManyToManyField(to='M3')

class M3(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Here you can query `M2` model and its relative `M1` objects using `select_relation` field and `M3` objects using `prefetch_relation` field.

However as we've mentioned `M1`'s relation from `M2` is a `ForeignKey`, it just returns only **1** record for any `M2` object. Same thing applies for `OneToOneField` as well.

But `M3`'s relation from `M2` is a `ManyToManyField` which might return any number of `M1` objects.

Consider a case where you have 2 `M2` objects `m21`, `m22` who have same **5** associated `M3` objects with IDs `1,2,3,4,5`. When you fetch associated `M3` objects for each of those `M2` objects, if you use select related, this is how it's going to work.

**Steps:**

1. Find `m21` object.
2. Query all the `M3` objects related to `m21` object whose IDs are `1,2,3,4,5`.
3. Repeat same thing for `m22` object and all other `M2` objects.

As we have same `1,2,3,4,5` IDs for both `m21`, `m22` objects, if we use select_related option, it's going to query the DB twice for the same IDs which were already fetched.

Instead if you use prefetch_related, when you try to get `M2` objects, it will make a note of all the IDs that your objects returned (Note: only the IDs) while querying `M2` table and as last step, Django is going to make a query to `M3` table with the set of all IDs that your `M2` objects have returned. and join them to `M2` objects using Python instead of database.

This way you're querying all the `M3` objects only once which improves performance as python joins are cheaper than database joins.

Answer (score 39):

Both methods achieve the same purpose, to forego unnecessary db queries. But they use different approaches for efficiency.

The only reason to use either of these methods is when a single large query is preferable to many small queries. Django uses the large query to create models in memory preemptively rather than performing on demand queries against the database.

`select_related` performs a join with each lookup, but extends the select to include the columns of all joined tables. However this approach has a caveat.

Joins have the potential to multiply the number of rows in a query. When you perform a join over a foreign key or one-to-one field, the number of rows won't increase. However, many-to-many joins do not have this guarantee. So, Django restricts `select_related` to relations that won't unexpectedly result in a massive join.

The *"join in python"* for `prefetch_related` is a little more alarming than it should be. It creates a separate query for each table to be joined. It filters each of these table with a WHERE IN clause, like:

```
SELECT "credential"."id",
       "credential"."uuid",
       "credential"."identity_id"
FROM   "credential"
WHERE  "credential"."identity_id" IN
    (84706, 48746, 871441, 84713, 76492, 84621, 51472);
```

Rather than performing a single join with potentially too many rows, each table is split into a separate query.

Answer (score 30):

###### [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related):

- can reduce multiple `SELECT` queries to only 1 `SELECT` query with **Forward Foreign Key** and **Reverse Foreign Key** in one-to-one relationship and with **Forward Foreign Key** in one-to-many and many-to-many relationships.
- cannot be used with **Reverse Foreign Key** in one-to-many and many-to-many relationships.

###### [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

- can reduce multiple `SELECT` queries to 2 `SELECT` queries as a minimum with **Forward Foreign Key** and **Reverse Foreign Key** in one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships.

*You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75262002/what-are-forward-foreign-key-and-reverse-foreign-key-in-django#answer-75285628) explaining the meaning of **Forward Foreign Key** and **Reverse Foreign Key**.

The following shows my experiments of `select_related()` and `prefetch_related()` with **Forward Foreign Key** and **Reverse Foreign Key** in one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships.

## <**One-to-one relationship**>

For example, there are `Person` and `PersonDetail` models which have **one-to-one relationship** as shown below:

```py
# "app/models.py

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PersonDetail(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.age) + " " + self.gender
```

And, there are `Person` and `PersonDetail` admins as shown below:

```py
# "app/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person, PersonDetail

class PersonDetailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PersonDetail
    
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (PersonDetailInline,)
    list_display = ('id', 'name')
    ordering = ('id',)

@admin.register(PersonDetail)
class PersonDetailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'age', 'gender', 'person')
    ordering = ('id',)
```

Then, `Person` admin has 5 objects as shown below:

[image]

And, `PersonDetail` admin has 5 objects as shown below:

[image]

### <**Forward Foreign Key**>

Then, I iterate `Person` model from `PersonDetail` model as shown below:

```py
for obj in PersonDetail.objects.all():
    print(obj.person)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
John
David
Lisa
Kai
Anna
```

Then, 6 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below. *I use PostgreSQL and these below are the query logs of PostgreSQL and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries#answer-75031321) explaining how to enable and disable the query logs on PostgreSQL:

[image]

Next, I iterate `Person` model from `PersonDetail` model with `select_related("person")` as shown below. *The order of `select_related()` and `all()` don't matter:

```py
for obj in PersonDetail.objects.select_related("person").all():
    print(obj.person)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
John
David
Lisa
Kai
Anna
```

Then, 1 `SELECT` query is run as shown below:

[image]

Next, I iterate `Person` model from `PersonDetail` model with `prefetch_related("person")` as shown below. *The order of `prefetch_related()` and `all()` don't matter:

```py
for obj in PersonDetail.objects.prefetch_related("person").all():
    print(obj.person)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
John
David
Lisa
Kai
Anna
```

Then, 2 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

### <**Reverse Foreign Key**>

Next, I iterate `PersonDetail` model from `Person` model as shown below:

```py
for obj in Person.objects.all():
    print(obj.persondetail)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
32 Male
18 Male
26 Female
36 Male
21 Female
```

Then, 6 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

Next, I iterate `PersonDetail` model from `Person` model with `select_related("persondetail")` as shown below:

```py
for obj in Person.objects.select_related("persondetail").all():
    print(obj.persondetail)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
32 Male
18 Male
26 Female
36 Male
21 Female
```

Then, 1 `SELECT` query is run as shown below:

[image]

Next, I iterate `PersonDetail` model from `Person` model with `prefetch_related("persondetail")` as shown below:

```py
for obj in Person.objects.prefetch_related("persondetail").all():
    print(obj.persondetail)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
32 Male
18 Male
26 Female
36 Male
21 Female
```

Then, 2 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

## <**One-to-many relationship**>

For example, there are `Category` and `Product` models which have **one-to-many relationship** as shown below:

```py
# "app/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.category) + " " + self.name + " " + str(self.price)
```

And, there are `Category` and `Product` admins as shown below:

```py
# "app/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Product
    
@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name')
    ordering = ('id',)

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'price', 'category')
    ordering = ('id',)
```

Then, `Category` admin has 4 objects as shown below:

[image]

And, `Product` admin has 6 objects as shown below:

[image]

### <**Forward Foreign Key**>

Then, I iterate `Category` model from `Product` model as shown below:

```py
for obj in Product.objects.all():
    print(obj.category)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
Fruits
Fruits
Vegetable
Meat
Meat
Fish
```

Then, 7 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

Next, I iterate `Category` model from `Product` model with `select_related("category")` as shown below:

```py
for obj in Product.objects.select_related("category").all():
    print(obj.category)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
Fruits
Fruits
Vegetable
Meat
Meat
Fish
```

Then, 1 `SELECT` query is run as shown below:

[image]

Next, I iterate `Category` model from `Product` model with `prefetch_related("category")` as shown below:

```py
for obj in Product.objects.prefetch_related("category").all():
    print(obj.category)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
Fruits
Fruits
Vegetable
Meat
Meat
Fish
```

Then, 2 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

### <**Reverse Foreign Key**>

Next, I iterate `Product` model from `Category` model as shown below:

```py
for obj in Category.objects.all():
    print(obj.product_set.all())
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
<QuerySet [<Product: Fruits Apple 10.00>, <Product: Fruits Orange 20.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Vegetable Carrot 30.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Meat Chicken 40.00>, <Product: Meat Beef 50.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Fish Salmon 60.00>]>
```

Then, 5 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

Next, I tries to iterate `Product` model from `Category` model with `select_related("product_set")` as shown below:

```py
for obj in Category.objects.select_related("product_set").all():
    print(obj.product_set.all())
```

Then, the error below occurs because `select_related("product_set")` cannot be used with **Reverse Foreign Key**:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in
> select_related: 'product_set'. Choices are: (none)

Actually, there is no error if I use `select_related()` with **no argument** as shown below:

```py
                                        # ↓ No argument
for obj in Category.objects.select_related().all():
    print(obj.product_set.all())
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
<QuerySet [<Product: Fruits Apple 10.00>, <Product: Fruits Orange 20.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Vegetable Carrot 30.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Meat Chicken 40.00>, <Product: Meat Beef 50.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Fish Salmon 60.00>]>
```

But, 5 `SELECT` queries are still run instead of 1 `SELECT` query as shown below:

[image]

Next, I iterate `Product` model from `Category` model with `prefetch_related("product_set")` as shown below:

```py
for obj in Category.objects.prefetch_related("product_set").all():
    print(obj.product_set.all())
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
<QuerySet [<Product: Fruits Apple 10.00>, <Product: Fruits Orange 20.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Vegetable Carrot 30.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Meat Chicken 40.00>, <Product: Meat Beef 50.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Fish Salmon 60.00>]>
```

Then, 2 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

## <**Many-to-many relationship**>

For example, `Category` and `Product` models have **many-to-many relationship** as shown below:

```py
# "app/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + str(self.price)
```

And, there are `Category` and `Product` admins as shown below:

```py
# "app/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Product
    
@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'get_products')
    ordering = ('id',)

    @admin.display(description='products')
    def get_products(self, obj):
        return [product.name for product in obj.product_set.all()]

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'price', 'get_categories')
    ordering = ('id',)

    @admin.display(description='categories')
    def get_categories(self, obj):
        return [category.name for category in obj.categories.all()]
```

Then, `Category` admin has 5 objects as shown below:

[image]

And, `Product` admin has 6 objects as shown below:

[image]

### <**Forward Foreign Key**>

Then, I iterate `Category` model from `Product` model as shown below:

```py
for obj in Product.objects.all():
    print(obj.categories.all())
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
<QuerySet [<Category: Fruits>, <Category: 20% OFF>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Fruits>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Vegetable>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Meat>, <Category: 20% OFF>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Meat>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Fish>, <Category: 20% OFF>]>
```

Then, 7 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

Next, I iterate `Category` model from `Product` model with `select_related("categories")` as shown below:

```py
for obj in Product.objects.select_related("categories").all():
    print(obj.categories.all())
```

Then, the error below occurs because `select_related("categories")` cannot be used with **Reverse Foreign Key**:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in
> select_related: 'categories'. Choices are: (none)

Actually, there is no error if I use `select_related()` with **no argument** as shown below:

```py
                                       # ↓ No argument
for obj in Product.objects.select_related().all():
    print(obj.categories.all())
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
<QuerySet [<Category: Fruits>, <Category: 20% OFF>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Fruits>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Vegetable>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Meat>, <Category: 20% OFF>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Meat>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Fish>, <Category: 20% OFF>]>
```

But, 7 `SELECT` queries are still run instead of 1 `SELECT` query as shown below:

[image]

Next, I iterate `Category` model from `Product` model with `prefetch_related("categories")` as shown below:

```py
for obj in Product.objects.prefetch_related("categories").all():
    print(obj.categories.all())
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
<QuerySet [<Category: Fruits>, <Category: 20% OFF>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Fruits>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Vegetable>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Meat>, <Category: 20% OFF>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Meat>]>
<QuerySet [<Category: Fish>, <Category: 20% OFF>]>
```

Then, 2 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

### <**Reverse Foreign Key**>

Next, I iterate `Product` model from `Category` model as shown below:

```py
for obj in Category.objects.all():
    print(obj.product_set.all())
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
<QuerySet [<Product: Apple 10.00>, <Product: Orange 20.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Carrot 30.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Chicken 40.00>, <Product: Beef 50.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Salmon 60.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Apple 10.00>, <Product: Chicken 40.00>, <Product: Salmon 60.00>]>
```

Then, 6 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

Next, I iterate `Product` model from `Category` model with `select_related("product_set")` as shown below:

```py
for obj in Category.objects.select_related("product_set").all():
    print(obj.product_set.all())
```

Then, the error below occurs because `select_related("categories")` cannot be used with **Reverse Foreign Key**:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in
> select_related: 'product_set'. Choices are: (none)

Actually, there is no error if I use `select_related()` with **no argument** as shown below:

```py
                                        # ↓ No argument
for obj in Category.objects.select_related().all():
    print(obj.product_set.all())
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
<QuerySet [<Product: Apple 10.00>, <Product: Orange 20.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Carrot 30.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Chicken 40.00>, <Product: Beef 50.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Salmon 60.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Apple 10.00>, <Product: Chicken 40.00>, <Product: Salmon 60.00>]>
```

But, 6 `SELECT` queries are still run instead of 1 `SELECT` query as shown below:

[image]

Next, I iterate `Product` model from `Category` model with `prefetch_related("product_set")` as shown below:

```py
for obj in Category.objects.prefetch_related("product_set").all():
    print(obj.product_set.all())
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
<QuerySet [<Product: Apple 10.00>, <Product: Orange 20.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Carrot 30.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Chicken 40.00>, <Product: Beef 50.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Salmon 60.00>]>
<QuerySet [<Product: Apple 10.00>, <Product: Chicken 40.00>, <Product: Salmon 60.00>]>
```

Then, 2 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

## <**Additional experiments**>

For example, there are `Country`, `State` and `City` models which have **one-to-many relationship** as shown below:

```py
# "app/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class State(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And, there are `Country`, `State` and `City` admins as shown below:

```py
# "app/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Country, State, City
    
@admin.register(Country)
class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name')
    ordering = ('id',)

@admin.register(State)
class StateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'get_country')
    ordering = ('id',)

    @admin.display(description='country')
    def get_country(self, obj):
        return obj.country

@admin.register(City)
class CityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'get_state', 'get_country')
    ordering = ('id',)

    @admin.display(description='state')
    def get_state(self, obj):
        print(obj)
        return obj.state

    @admin.display(description='country')
    def get_country(self, obj):
        return obj.state.country
```

Then, `Country` admin has 2 objects as shown below:

[image]

And, `State` admin has 3 objects as shown below:

[image]

Then, `City` admin has 6 objects as shown below:

[image]

### <**Forward Foreign Key**>

Then, I iterate `Country` model from `City` model with `select_related("state__country")` as shown below:

```py
for obj in City.objects.all().select_related("state__country"):
    print(obj.state.country)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
USA
USA
USA
USA
Japan
Japan
```

Then, 1 `SELECT` query is run as shown below:

[image]

Next, I iterate `Country` model from `City` model with `prefetch_related("state__country")` as shown below:

```py
for obj in City.objects.all().prefetch_related("state__country"):
    print(obj.state.country)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
USA
USA
USA
USA
Japan
Japan
```

Then, 3 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

### <**Reverse Foreign Key**>

Next, I iterate `City` model from `Country` model with `prefetch_related("state_set__city_set")` as shown below:

```py
for country_obj in Country.objects.all().prefetch_related("state_set__city_set"):
    for state_obj in country_obj.state_set.all():
        for city_obj in state_obj.city_set.all():
            print(city_obj)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
San Francisco
Los Angeles
San Diego
Kansas City
Ginza
Akihabara
```

Then, 3 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

Next, I iterate `City` model from `Country` model with `prefetch_related("state_set__city_set")` with [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#filter) instead of [all()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#all) as shown below. *`prefetch_related()` with `filter()` doesn't work:

```py
                                  # Here
for country_obj in Country.objects.filter().prefetch_related("state_set__city_set"):
    for state_obj in country_obj.state_set.filter(): # Here
        for city_obj in state_obj.city_set.filter(): # Here
            print(city_obj)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
San Francisco
Los Angeles
San Diego
Kansas City
Ginza
Akihabara
```

Then, 8 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

So to reduce 8 `SELECT` queries, I need to use [Prefetch()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) with `filter()` but I only know how to iterate `State` model from `Country` model with `Prefetch()` and `filter()` as shown below. *I asked [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75306441/how-to-use-prefetch-with-filter-to-reduce-select-queries-to-iterate-3) on Stack Overflow about how to iterate `City` model from `Country` model with `Prefetch()` and `filter()`:

```py
for country_obj in Country.objects.filter().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('state_set', # Here
        queryset=State.objects.filter(),
        to_attr='state_obj'
    )
):
    print(country_obj.state_obj)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
[<State: California>, <State: Missouri>]
[<State: Tokyo>]
```

Then, 2 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below:

[image]

Comment: one of the most comprehensive answer

Answer (score 4):

Don't be confused 
 **select_related:** Use for ForeignKey relationship,
**prefetch_related:** Use for ManyToManyField relationship or reverse ForeignKey.
They doing the same thing reducing the number of query 
For example:

```
class ExampleClassA(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ExampleClassB(models.Model):
    example_class_a = models.ForeignKey(ExampleClassA,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)



objects = ExampleClassB.objects.all() 

for obj in objects:
    print(obj.example_class_a.title)
```

Number of query(access related field): N+1 (# n is number of ExampleClassA's object)
if we use this query:

```
objects = ExampleClassB.objects.select_related('example_class_a').all()
```

Number of query is only one.

Answer (score 4):

Let me try to show you how Django is going to make db calls in select_related and prefetch_related

```
class a(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class b(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

#select_related query->

```
b.objects.select_related('a').first()
```

SQL query executed for this would be

```
SELECT * FROM "b" LEFT OUTER JOIN "a" ON ("b"."a_id" = "a"."id") LIMIT 1
```

Here Django will get "a" model details using JOIN

#prefetch_related query->

```
B.objects.prefetch_related('a').first()
```

SQL query executed for this would be

```
SELECT * FROM "b" LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM "a" WHERE "a"."id" IN (ids collected from above query)
```

Here Django will execute two SQL query and merge them through python