# Query optimization: howto

Tags: django, django-models

I have my models like this:

```
class Personne(BaseModel):
    # [skip] many fields then:
    photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, blank=True,
                                    through='PersonnePhoto',
                                    symmetrical=False,
                                    related_name='parent')
    def photo_profil(self):
        a = PersonnePhoto.objects.filter(
            personne=self, photo_type=PersonnePhoto.PHOTO_PROFIL)
        return a[0] if len(a) else None

    # [skip] many fields then:
    travels = models.ManyToManyField(
            TagWithValue, blank=True,
            through='PersonneTravel',
            default=None, symmetrical=False,
            related_name='personne_travel')

class PersonneRelation(BaseModel):
    src = models.ForeignKey('Personne', related_name='src')
    dst = models.ForeignKey('Personne', related_name='dst')
    opposite = models.ForeignKey('PersonneRelation',
                                 null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    is_reverse = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I need to show all contacts of one person, and for each contact, show all his/her travels, and his/her photo.

Here's my code in my view:

```
class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'my_home/contacts/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['contacts'] = Personne.objects.get(
                user=self.request.user).relations.all()
        return context
```

Pretty simple.

The problem is in my template. `my_home/contacts/index.html` includes `contact_detail.html` for each contact:

```
    {% for c in contacts %}
        {% with c as contact %}
            {% include 'includes/contact_detail.html' %}
        {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
```

In `contact_detail.html`, I call `photo_profil`, which makes a query to get the value of the picture of the contact.

```
{{ contact.photo_profil }}
```

*This implies that if a user has 100 contacts, I will do* **one query for all his contacts, then 100 queries for each contact**. How is it possible to optimize this? I have the same problem for travels, and the same problem for each ManyToMany fields of the contact, actually.

Comment: It looks like you can use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). You can also take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm).

Comment: May I ask you to give just a sample that could work with, for example, "photo"?

Comment: When I try to do something like `Personne.objects.get(user=self.request.user).relations.select_related('travels')` there's an error and Django wants only to select ForeignKey fields, not ManyToMany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need some [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) goodness:

```
context['contacts'] = (Personne.objects
                       .get(user=self.request.user)
                       .relations
                       .all()
                       .prefetch_related('travels', 'photos'))
```

Note, however, that it will fetch **all** the contacts' photos, which is not you seem to expect. Basically you have two options here. Either add some hairy raw SQL to the [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) object's `queryset` parameter. Or (as I did in one of the projects) designate a separate `main_photo` field for storing the user's avatar (a separate `ForeignKey` to the `Photo`, I mean, not the completely independent one). Yes, it's clearly a denormalization, but queries become *much* more simple. And your users get a way to set a main photo, after all.