# Update Django from 1.6 to 1.8: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-select-related

I update project from Django 1.6.7 to 1.8.7 and I have got following exception with Django 1.8, although with Django 1.6 it code was right:

```
In[2]: from apps.route import models
In[3]: models.Trace.objects.select_related("trace_points")
Out[3]: <repr(<django.db.models.query.QuerySet at 0x3b50c10>) failed: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'trace_points'. Choices are: user>
```

My models:

```
class Trace(SocialMixin, models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='traces')
    name = models.CharField(u'Название', max_length=255)
    rating = RatingField(range=5, weight=0)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(u'Дата старта')
    finish_date = models.DateTimeField(u'Дата окончания', null=True, blank=True)
    distance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=6, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    hits = generic.GenericRelation(HitCount, object_id_field='object_pk')
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class TracePoint(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, blank=True)
    trace = models.ForeignKey(Trace, related_name="trace_points")
```

I also have this bug into DetailView on Trace, DetailView uses get_related_selections, and of course I got "FieldError: Invalid field name...", to avoid error I have to use ManyToManyField instead of ForeigenKey?

Comment: The code in `[3]` makes no sense, since there can be more than one `TracePoint` associated with a `Trace`.

Comment: Yes, there is can be more TracePoint than one that associated with a Trace, but in old Django it really worked...

Comment: That would be a bug in the old version then.

Comment: I also have this bug into DetailView, DetailView uses get_related_selections, and of course I got "FieldError: Invalid field name...", to avoid error I have to use ManyToManyField instead of ForeigenKey?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Django 1.8 [checks that the fields given in select_related are correct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.8/#select-related-now-checks-given-fields). The `select_related` method can be used for foreign keys and one to one fields. It is not possible to use it for the reverse relationship `Trace` back to `TracePoint`.

In previous versions of Django, `Trace.objects.select_related("trace_points")` would not raise an error, but the `select_related()` call would have no effect.

You can either remove the `select_related()` call, or replace it with [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), which will work.

```
Trace.objects.prefetch_related('trace_points')
```

Comment: However, it's important to note that using prefetch_related() could yield different results compared to those obtained from select_related().

Comment: @caot I don’t follow. `select_related` didn’t have any effect in the code above. In what  circumstances could adding `prefetch_related` return different results?

Answer (score 7):

Django's [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) doesn't works for backwards foreignkey relations.

You might want to use [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for prefetching all trace points at python level.

```
models.Trace.objects.prefetch_related("trace_points")
```

Comment: However, it's important to note that using prefetch_related() could yield different results compared to those obtained from select_related().

Answer (score 0):

With **Reverse Foreign Key** in one-to-many relationship, [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) doesn't work while [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) works. *[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75262002/what-are-forward-foreign-key-and-reverse-foreign-key-in-django/75285628#75285628) explains what is **Reverse Foreign Key** and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm/75275706#75275706) explains more about `select_related()` and `prefetch_related()`.

So, you need to use `prefetch_related()` instead of `select_related()` as shown below:

```py
Trace.objects.prefetch_related('trace_points')
# Trace.objects.select_related("trace_points")
```