# What are "Forward Foreign Key" and "Reverse Foreign Key" in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, reverse-foreign-key

When reading the topics related to Django's [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) and [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) on some websites including **Stack Overflow**, I frequently see the words **Forward Foreign Key** and **Reverse Foreign Key** but I couldn't find the definitions on Django Documentation:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
```

So, what are **Forward Foreign Key** and **Reverse Foreign Key** in Django?

Answer (score 7):

- **Forward Foreign Key** means that the child model which has the foreign key to the parent model accesses the parent model.
- **Reverse Foreign Key** means that a parent model accesses the child model which has the foreign key to the parent model.

So in your case, because `Product` model has the foreign key to `Category` model so `Category` model is a parent model and `Product` model is a child model as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model): # Parent model
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Product(models.Model): # Child model
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
```

### <**Forward Foreign Key**>

The child model `Product` accesses the parent model `Category` with `obj.category.name` as shown below:

```py
for obj in Product.objects.all():
    print(obj.category.name) # Here
```

### <**Reverse Foreign Key**>

The parent model `Category` accesses the child model `Product` with `obj.product_set.all()` as shown below:

```py
for obj in Category.objects.all():
    print(obj.product_set.all()) # Here
```

Answer (score 0):

Forward foreignKey is the Product models relation to the the Category model, where each product has to have a category. A reverse foreign key is the relation of the Category model to the Product model and a Category can have many Products as reverse foreignKey.