# Python : How to pass the value of a foreign key in my Django template?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-views

I have created a Bid model so that type-2 users can bid on some 'Post' created by type-1 users. For achieving this, I made a foreign key for post field in the model 'Bid'.

Actually i wanted to relate the bids to a particular post with auto generated 'id' in the 'post' model. So i placed the get_absolute_url beside Post 'id' in my template. I am new to django and I am not sure whether it works for what i want or not.

How can i relate the bid with post_id to a particular post in the template so that i can get a bid amount placed by various type-2 users for a particular post? I would appreciate helping me solve this.

Here's my code:

Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    post_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    from1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    objects = PostManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_id

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"id": self.post_id})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-Time"]

class Bid(models.Model):

    bid_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=uuid.uuid4, related_name='bids' )
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, unique=False)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("accept_bid", kwargs={"bid_id": self.bid_id})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.amount

    def __str__(self):
        return self.amount
```

forms.py:

```
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):
    // Defined a post field as ModelChoiceField
    post = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Post.objects.all(), label="Post", widget=forms.RadioSelect(), initial=0)
    amount = forms.IntegerField(help_text='Place the bid for a Post')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(BidForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['post'].queryset = Post.objects.all

    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ["amount"]
```

views.py:

```
def live_bid_truck(request, **kwargs):
    if request.method=='post':
        form = BidForm(request.POST or None)

        if  form.is_valid():
         bid = form.save(post)
         bid = form.save(commit=False)
         print(form.cleaned_data.get('amount'))
         bid.user = request.user
         bid.post = form.cleaned_data['post'] // Set my post here


         bid.save()
    else:
        form=BidForm()
        post_queryset = Post.objects.all()
        context = {
        "post_queryset": post_queryset, 
        "title": "List",
        'form': form,

    }
        return render(request, 'loggedin_truck/live_bid_truck.html', context)
```

live_bid_truck.html

```
{% for post in post_queryset %}
<table class="table table-striped, sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>Load No.</th>
            <th>From</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr> // Returns the post_queryset with radio buttons
            <td >{{form.post}} </td>
            <td>{{ post.from1 }}</a><br/></td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-striped, sortable "  style="margin-top: 10px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>     
            <form class="nomargin" method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
            <td>{% render_field  form.amount  class="form-control" %}</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>

<input type='submit' value='Post Bid'/></form>

{% endfor %}
```

Update - 1:

Views.py:

```
def live_bids(request):
    post_queryset = Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('bids')
    bid_queryset = Bid.objects.all().order_by('amount')

    context = {
        "post_queryset": post_queryset,
        "bid_queryset": bid_queryset,
        "title": "List",
    }
    return render(request, 'loggedin_load/live_bids.html', context)
```

live_bids.html:

```
{% for post in post_queryset %}
{{post.id}}
{% for bid in post.bids.all %}
{{bid.amount}}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You probably want to show us your form. Is it a ModelForm you are using?

Comment: @wobbily_col. I updated my code. Yes, i am using model form. I haven't included any post field in my model form. If required, How can i do it?

Comment: @wobbily_col. I stuck at this point from last 2 days. i couldn't able to move forward. Can you please help me in solve this one.

Comment: Try rendering the form in your template as {{ form }} instead of {% render_field  form.amount  class="form-control" %}. (Sorry I am kind of busy to post a proper reply).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the goal is to be able to list the related bidders/bids on the post? If so, then you can use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) (if you're selecting parents from child) of [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) (if you're doing a reverse lookup)

1) First of all in your Bid model better `related_name` would be "bids", like so;

```
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=1, related_name='bids' )
```

2) Secondly inside `def live_bid_truck(request):` make the post query like this so that you would get all the related objects in one database hit.;

```
Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('bids')
```

3) Then in your template you can use can access the related bids for the post

```
{% for bid in post.bids.all %} // In your case post is obj
    {{ bid }}  // Access whatever you need from the bid like {{ bid.user }}
{% endfor %}
```

You should be able to call `post.bids.all` and receive values even without prefetch by just [following the backward relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward). If you're not getting any values, then you probably are not setting them properly. `prefetch_related` helps with the performance as the number of posts increase.

---

FROM YOUR CODE

In your `BidForm` there is no reference to the `post` and I don't know if you have it in your custom save() method or not. When you save this form as it is, `post_id` will be the default value 1

```
# NO REFENCE TO post
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):

 class Meta:
    model = Bid
    fields = ["amount"]
```

Also in your `view` you don't set the post either.

```
def live_bid_truck(request):

    form = BidForm(request.POST or None)

    if  form.is_valid():
        bid = form.save(commit=False)

        print(form.cleaned_data.get("amount"))
        bid.user = request.user # YOU SET THE USER 
        bid.post = ?? # YOU DON'T SET THE POST HERE EITHER, 
                      # SO ALL YOUR BIDS HAVE THE DEFAULT POST id = 1
                      # DO YOU ACTUALLY HAVE POST with id = 1?

        bid.save()

        # WHAT HAPPENS IF YOU PRINT BID POST ID HERE ?? 
        # CHECK HERE IF YOU REALLY HAVE THE RELATED POST ID.
        print(bid.post.id)
```

Comment: After i placed an amount in my BidForm in live_bid_truck.html, the value is stored in my database. But i couldn't able to get the amount value for a particular post in live_bids.html. I updated my code in the question. Could you once again help me!!!

Comment: In you update I see you're using `prefetch_related` which should be `select_related` as you're trying to follow ForeignKey relations.See [this question for the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm)

Comment: Also in your model, `related_name` still looks like *"posts"*. If the `related_name` is still *"posts"* then use `select_related('posts')`

Comment: As it is Reverse ForeignKey relationship i used prefetch_related. Any way i don't know why i couldn't able to get amount value in live_bids.html.

Comment: Assuming you have this `post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=1, related_name='bids' )` in your `Bid` model, could you please try `Post.objects.all().select_related('bids')`

Comment: when i do this it raising an error: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'bids'. Choices are: user

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I'm making a mistake with the second `select_related` . Even if you don't prefetch, when you access it via `post.bids.all`, although not efficient it should list the bids. What do you get, empty values or an error?

Comment: When i use select_related: it returns - FieldError at /live_bids/
Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'bids'. Choices are: user

With prefetch_related: emptyvalues

Comment: @Tiny_Instance I am new to django and it is hard to move further. Could you help me to solve why i getting an error when i use select_related &  empty values when i use prefetch_related

Comment: In your `BidForm` you only have `amount` field. And in your view you only assign `user`. Are you sure are also assigning the related `post` ForeignKey and saving? If you don't have `post` in your form then you need to assign it like you did the `instance.user = request.user` before saving. You're getting empty values, probably because you forgot to assign and save.

Comment: so for associating a post to the bids, in my live_bid_truck.views should I need to add instance.post_id = request.post_id?

Comment: in my Post model, instead of autogenerated id i included post_id as UUIDField for associating the post field in Bid Model. So, how can i write to associate a particular post_id to bids in live_bid_truck view?

Comment: `Bid` model has a `post` field, you need to set it to the correct post, otherwise all the bids will belong to `post` with id=1 because of the `default=1` value. You need to know which `post` the user is bidding for inside live_bid_truck right?

Comment: Yes(These letters are for sake of stackoverflow)

Comment: I updated the answer, added extra comments tried to show the possible flaws. Please check all the comments and I hope these help.

Comment: I used ModelChoiceField for 'post' field in forms.py as in my updated code. Now, i am again facing trouble for how can i render this in my template. I use a custom radio button in my template and with {% for choice in form.post.field.queryset %} it return the whole queryset in each row of my table, and with {% for choice in form.post.field.choices %} it raising an error object of type 'method' has no len() may because of using UUID field. And i am not sure how can i save it in my views also as you mentioned in your updated answer. Could you help me in solving this one more time