# invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to do an inner join on these 3 tables using PersonScore but it can't find persontype. What am i doing wrong?

models:

```
class PersonScore(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    person = models.ForeignKey(‘Person’)

class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class PersonType(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(‘Person’)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

code:

```
PersonScore.objects.filter(person__name="Bob").prefetch_related("person__persontype")
```

error:

```
Cannot find 'persontype' on Person object, 'person__persontype' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()
```

code:

```
PersonScore.objects.filter(person__name="Bob").prefetch_related("person__persontype_set")
```

error:

```
KeyError: (1L,)
```

Comment: is there still problem ? or solved ?

Answer (score 15):

In the PersonScore you should to use select_related instead of prefetch_related

```
    PersonScore.objects.filter(person__name="Bob").select_related("person__persontype")
```

if you want to use prefetch_related, you will use it with Person

```
    Person.objects.filter(personscore_set__name="Bob").prefetch_related("personscore_set"
```

you can check more details here: [What's the difference between select_related and prefetch_related in Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm)

I hope that will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use select_related from foreignkey side(i.e. in this case, PersonScore or PersonType) on 1:N relationship, or on OneToOneRelationship.

So,

```py
PersonScore.objects.filter(person__name="Bob").select_related("person__persontype")
```

will throw `FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'persontype'. Choices are: (none)`, because you can't JOIN from Person to PersonType

On the other hand, you can use prefetch_related on N:M, 1:N, 1:1 on either side. The reason why you would use prefetch_related on 1:N or 1:1 is that even though it takes more query than select_related is that you can control the operation of prefetching using `Prefetch`. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

For example, you can use ordered PersonType as your queryset to prefetch. Of course, you can do much more than this.

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch


PersonScore.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'person__persontype_set',
        queryset=PersonType.objects.order_by('type')
    )
).filter(person__name='Bob')
```

Checking with django 3.2.18 and 4.2, `PersonScore.objects.filter(person__name="Bob").prefetch_related("person__persontype_set")` should do the job. If you are getting `KeyError: (1L,)` the problem may lie somewhere else.

With `PersonScore.objects.filter(person__name="Bob").prefetch_related("person__persontype")`, you should use "person__persontype_set" for parameter. If you want to use "person_persontype", set `related_name` to `persontype`:

```py
class PersonScore(models.Model):
    ...
    person = models.ForeignKey(
'<app_label>.Person', related_name='persontype')
```