# Terrible Django Admin Performance

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I am developing a Django project, which already got plenty of real world data so I can see its performance.

The performances of few DjangoAdmin lists are just terrible.

I have one admin list, lets call it `devices`. In that list I am fetching additional informations for each row, those fields are related from other tables and connected via FK/PK/M2N.

List contains about 500 records and loading of that screen takes, according to `django-debug-toolbar`, around 6.5 seconds, which is unbearable.

This admin class

```
@admin.register(Device)
class DeviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_select_related = True
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'project', 'location', 'machine', 'type', 'last_maintenance_log')
    inlines = [CommentInline, TestLogInline]

    def project(self, obj):
        try:
            return Device.objects.get(pk=obj.pk).machine.location.project.project_name
        except AttributeError:
            return '-'

    def location(self, obj):
        try:
            return Device.objects.get(pk=obj.pk).machine.location.name
        except AttributeError:
            return '-'

    def last_maintenance_log(self, obj):
        try:
            log = AdminLog.objects.filter(object_id=obj.pk).latest('time')
            return '{} | {}'.format(log.time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %-I:%M %p"), log.title)
        except AttributeError:
            return '-'
```

All `Machine`, `Location` and `Project` are tables in database.

After looking into queries in `django-debug-toolbar` I discovered something terrible.
That screen required ***287*** sql queries ! Yes, over two hundreds!

Is there anything I can do to reduce this time to something reasonable?

EDIT:
Thanks to Bruno I removed `Device.objects.get(pk=obj.id)` (as it was really redundant, I totally overlooked this.

So everywhere i put `obj.` for example `obj.machine.location.project.project_name`

Only this alone reduces the speed and query count to half, so far so good.

I not have trouble fusing `obj` approach and `select_related` approach. This is my current code, which is worse than only `obj` approach.

```
def project(self, obj):
        try:
            Device.objects.select_related('machine__location__project').get(id=obj.pk).machine.location.project.project_name
        except AttributeError:
            return '-'
```

Which creates a nice INNER JOINs in queries, but the performance is around 15% worse than without it and using only `obj.machine.location.project.project_name`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT2:

Best performance I got is with this code:

```
@admin.register(Device)
class DeviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_select_related = True
    save_as = True
    form = DeviceForm
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'project', 'location', 'machine', 'type', 'last_maintenance_log')
    inlines = [CommentInline, TestLogInline]

    def project(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.machine.location.project.project_name
        except AttributeError:
            return '-'

    def location(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.machine.location.name
        except AttributeError:
            return '-'

    def last_maintenance_log(self, obj):
        try:
            log = AdminLog.objects.filter(object_id=obj.pk).latest('time')
            return '{} | {}'.format(log.time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %-I:%M %p"), log.title)
        except AttributeError:
            return '-'

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Device.objects.select_related('machine__location__project').all()
```

Which pushed this down to 104 queries (from almost 300) and time reduction over 50%. Can this be improved any further?

Comment: The number of queries is not surprising. From what I see you are doing 3 extra queries *per row* to get the data for the methods.

Comment: Well, yes, it is not so suprising with this approach, but I am wondering if is this somehow avoidable, I'll like to keep those extra info, but the cost is just too high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, avoid totally useless queries - this:

```
Device.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
```

is as useless as can be since `obj` **already** the `Device` instance you are looking for.

Then [override your `DeviceAdmin.get_queryset` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) to make proper use of [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) so you only have the minimal required number of queries.

Comment: Hello Bruno, thanks for your input, I am going to try this right now and report back the results!

Comment: Just by omiting the useless queries I managed to drop the querycount to half (125), continuing with select_related and prefetch_related, even though it is not as clear as I would imagine it.

Comment: @JosefKorbel you may want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm

Comment: Nice reading, I did understand it somehow, but it did not help, it is worse in fact. Dont you mind reading my edited question?

Comment: Looks like your last attempt is getting better.