# Django ForeignKey data grouping

Tags: django

Django ForeignKey need to grouping

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('headline',)
```

I want to list of all reporter with their all article showing the below format. How It possible?

```
-------------------------------
Reporter Name |  Total Article
-------------------------------
Reporter 1    |   3
-------------------------------
Reporter 2    |   4
-------------------------------
```

Comment: There is ample documentation and many tutorials on how to do that. What reserach have you done?

Comment: I tried many docs. Is it needed manytomany attach to Reporter to get data?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm)

Comment: Please check updated ques

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list all reporters you can use `Reporter.objects.all()` it will return you a queryset of all reporters, and for getting Articles of them use reverse relationship i.e - 
`reporter_object.article_set` because you didn't define any related name. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django)

I can give you an simple example how you can print All reporters with their Articles -

```
for reporter in Reporter.objects.all():
    print(reporter)
    for article in reporter.article_set.all():
        print(article)
```

when you defined a ForeignKey relationship, a one to many relationship is created between Reporter and Article, additionally one more attribute is added in Reporter, by default it is the name of your model with the suffix `_set` i.e article_set but when you specify the `related_name` then that will be same as your `related_name`, now you can easily call article by its related name with object of Reporter.

Still have any doubts comment it.