# Date ranges prefetch gives multiple entries instead of 1

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

The following returns 3 objects but this should be only 1. Since there is only 1 InsiderTrading object that has these filters, but there are 3 owners.

```
quarter_trading_2018q1 = InsiderTrading.objects.filter(
    issuer=company_issuer.pk,
    owners__company=company.pk,
    transaction_date__range=["2018-01-01", "2018-03-30"]
).prefetch_related('owners')
```

[image]

If I however remove the owner_company filter it return 1 (correct behaviour)

```
quarter_trading_2018q1 = InsiderTrading.objects.filter(
    issuer=company_issuer.pk,
    transaction_date__range=["2018-01-01", "2018-03-30"]
).prefetch_related('owners')
```

[image]

But I still want to filter on owners_company, how do I get 1 returned then?

Comment: Can you post the model structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct).

```
InsiderTrading.objects.filter(
    issuer=company_issuer.pk,
    owners__company=company.pk,
    transaction_date__range=["2018-01-01", "2018-03-30"]
).distinct().prefetch_related('owners')
```

Answer (score 0):

If `distinct` works: this means that this query results with

```
InsiderTrading.objects.filter(
    issuer=company_issuer.pk,
    owners__company=company.pk,
    transaction_date__range=["2018-01-01", "2018-03-30"]
)
```

with multiple results not one.

Django docs states

> select_related() "follows" foreign-key relationships, selecting
>   additional related-object data when it executes its query.
>
> prefetch_related() does a separate lookup for each relationship, and
>   does the "joining" in Python.

I'd say use `select_related` instead.
check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31237071/4117381

Another solution is to use `group_by` owner_id.