# Using lazy loading with DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to make a simple `lazy loading` with Django Rest Framework. 
I have a solid background with `Laravel` where you can simply use it like so:

```
Subscription::with('company')->paginate()
```

But with DRF I'm having problems. One Company can have **one subscription** and my models are defined as such:

**Company**

```py
class CompanyManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class Company(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
        Company refers to what we have referee in the official document as "Empresa Partner"

        Attributes:
            name: The name of the main company
            email: Email to contact the main company
            code: the code attributed to this company
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    our_system_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CompanyManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**Subscription**

```py
class Subscription(models.Model):
    """
    Subscriptions that references the plans and the companies
    :company:
        The owner of this subscription

    :plan:
        The plan this subscription is based on

    :starts:
        When the subscription starts

    :ends:
        When this subscription ends
    """
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    starts = models.DateTimeField()
    ends = models.DateTimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I have tried using `select_related` referred by this answer [What's the difference between select_related and prefetch_related in Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm) but every time I make a request to the endpoint it doesn't show the related `Company` of the `Subscription`

How I'm using `select_related`:

```py
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Subscription.objects\
            .all().select_related('company')\
            .order_by('-created_at')
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

        if page is not None:
            serializer = SubscriptionSerializer(
                page,
                many=True,
            )

            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

In my `SubscriptionSerliazer`:

```py
class SubscriptionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = (
            'company',
            'plan',
            'starts',
            'ends',
            'created_at',
        )
```

Comment: I think this is more realating to Django than DRF, and in django, all query set is lazy by default. - [Queryset are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)

Comment: I'm fairly new to Django/DRF and I'm trying to make the relationship between Django/DRF concepts and Laravel concepts. My problem here may seem in the SubscriptionSerialization for some reason (at least that's my understanding). That is why the DRF tag

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/ also seems would be interesting for you
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Comment: @iklinac Thank you so much. I thought DRF understood the relationships of Django and there was no need to define them. Thank you for the link and after reading it it solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the fields of a related model rather than just its primary key, you need to define a serializer for the related model (here: `CompanySerializer`) and direct the parent serializer to use it:

```
class SubscriptionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = (
            'company',
            # ...
        )
```

Comment: Thank you Endre. As stated in my comments I thought DRF understood the relationship that came with Django and there was no need to "serialize" them. Thank you