# Django model query all fields including the ManyToManyField in a single command

Tags: python, django, django-models

While playing around with the `ManyToManyField`, I wondered is there a way you can query a `ManyToManyField` automatically the same way you'd do a `ForeignKey` using `select_related()`?

Tables:

```
class Author(models.Model):
  fullname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Foo(models.Model):
  bar = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
  author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

In order to get the data I need from `Book` I usually do:

```
book = Book.objects.select_related('foo').get(pk=1)
authors = book.author.all()
```

which makes 2 trips. Is there a way to combine them the way `select_related()` does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between select\_related and prefetch\_related in Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `prefetch_related` for M2M field

```
Book.objects.select_related('foo').prefetch_related('author').values('author', 'title').get(pk=1)
```