# Django: How to filter data with many-to-many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Suppose that I have models like these:

***models.py***

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name='Name')
    order_num = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Order Number')

class Advertisement_Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name='Name')
    ad_category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name='Ad Category')

class Advertisement(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name='Title')    
    ad_type = models.ForeignKey(Advertisement_Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Advertisement Type')
```

How can I retrieve advertisement by category and advertisement type in such format by using **filters only?** Is this possible? Because the only way I can think of is querying everything and then building the dictionary/JSON manually through a number of for-loops and if-else which I would like to avoid.

***Expected format/output***

```
advertisement_type: {
    name: 'Type 1',
    category: {'Health', 'Engineering'},
    advertisement: {ads1, ads2, ads3}, # Can these be objects?
},
advertisement_type: {
    name: 'Type 2',
    category: {'Math', 'Numbers'},
    advertisement: {ads4, ads5, ads6}, # Can these be objects?
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To get related objects of a model you can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) which can [work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm) with *ManyToMany* relations.

In the example `ads_types`, `ad_category`, `advertisement_set` are QuerySets, so they return a list of objects and can be filtered as well.

```
ads_types = Advertisement_Type.objects.prefetch_related('ad_category', 'advertisement_set')

res = []
for adt in ads_type:
  res.append({
    "name": adt.name,
    "category": adt.ad_category.values_list('name', flat=True),
    "advertisement": adt.advertisement_set.values_list('title', flat=True),
  })
```

Or you can check [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) [serializers for related objects](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) to get json object representation along with relations.

You might also improve ManyToMany field by adding [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) option.