# Slow query using Django and PostgreSQL with > 40 million rows

Tags: django, postgresql, performance

I'm working with a model (table) with more than 40 million rows and queries are very slow (> 2 min), using PostgreSQL.

The models:

```py
class ModelA(...):
    source = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, related_name='source', ...)
    target = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, related_name='target', ...)

class ModelB(...):
    c = models.ForeignKey(ModelC, ...)
    ...
```

The Django filter:

```py
ModelA.objects.filter(source__isnull=True, target__c=my_c)
```

The query:

```sql
SELECT "model_a"."id", ... 
FROM "model_a" 
INNER JOIN "model_b" T3 ON ("model_a"."target_id" = T3."id") 
WHERE ("model_a"."removed" = False AND "model_a"."source_id" IS NULL AND T3."c_id" = 389)
```

Explain query:

```sh
                                                            QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1001.26..2498957.37 rows=12277 width=71)
   Workers Planned: 3
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.26..2496729.67 rows=3960 width=71)
         ->  Parallel Index Scan using model_b_model_c_removed_filename on model_b t3  (cost=0.69..2481771.88 rows=5907 width=4)
               Index Cond: (c_id = 389)
         ->  Index Scan using model_a_source_target_idx on model_a  (cost=0.56..2.52 rows=1 width=71)
               Index Cond: (target_id = t3.id)
               Filter: (NOT removed)
(8 rows)
```

How can I optimize it?

I am having optimization problems and I would like to know different solutions, etc.

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN YOU QUERY` and put query execution plane here

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev The `EXPLAIN` was added. Thx

Answer (score 1):

1. In Django you can use select_related and prefetch_related to
   optimized your queries.
2. You can add indexing into your models.
3. Use Redis or Memcached for caching layer to optimized read access.

[What's the difference between select_related and prefetch_related in Django ORM? Stack over flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm)

[select_related Django official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

[prefetch_related Django official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

[Solving Performance Problems in the Django ORM](https://medium.com/@hansonkd/performance-problems-in-the-django-orm-1f62b3d04785)

[Django Database Optimization Tips](https://medium.com/better-programming/django-database-optimization-tips-4e11631dbc2c)

Comment: I try with `select_related` and `prefetch_related` but still slow. Thanks for all the documentation

Comment: You can also try with NoSql databases for fast data access. Multiple techniques are used to tackle this kind of task. One factor is system specs.