# Trying to convert Left Join of SQL into Django query-set?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

here is my models.py file

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    """All Customers details goes here"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    firm_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Customer."""

        verbose_name = 'Customer'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Customers'

    def __str__(self):
        """Unicode representation of Customer."""
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    """All order details goes here.It has OneToMany relationship with  Customer"""
    STATUS = (
        ('CR', 'CR'),
        ('DR', 'DR'),
    )

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    bill_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    payment_date=models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=STATUS, null=False)
    amount = models.FloatField(max_length=255, null=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Order."""

        verbose_name = 'Order'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Orders'

    def __str__(self):
        """Unicode representation of Order."""
        return self.bill_name
```

i want to access only Customer's name and all fields of Order,in short i want to convert the following SQL in Django Query-set

> select name ,bill_name ,status from accounts_customer left join
> accounts_order on accounts_customer.id = accounts_order.customer_id
> where accounts_order.status="DR";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To attach the customer's name on the order object, you can use `annotate` with an `F` expression.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations

```py
orders = Order.objects.annotate(
    customer_name=F('customer__name')
).filter(status='DR')

for order in orders:
    print(order.customer_name)
```

---

If you suspect you will want to access more customer attributes, you may want to `select_related` (slightly more memory, larger query). [What's the difference between select_related and prefetch_related in Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm)

```py
orders = Order.objects.select_related('customer').filter(status='DR')

for order in orders:
    print(order.customer.name)
```

Comment: Thank you buddy,It was a great help with an awesome explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can perform join operation using two ways:
1st: via using select_related
I.e. Order.objects.select_related('customer')
And
2nd: via using filter:
I.e. Order.objects.filter(status__iexact="DR")

Comment: Thanks buddy,you've been a great help!!