# What is the best method for retrieving all objects associated with a foreign key using Django rest_framework?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a React application where I'm using Django+REST for the API and backend. On the frontend, I send a POST request to create a `Job` model and run the job. In the response, I retrieve the ID of the new `Job` object.

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/jobs/', query)
 .then((resp) => {
   setActiveJobs([...activeJobs, resp.data.id])
 }, (error) => {
   console.log(error)
 })
```

When the job finishes running, it creates multiple `Result` objects associated to it by a ForeignKey. These are my two models:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    query = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

class Result(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    result_no = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    ... more fields
```

I'm having trouble using rest_framework in Django to send a GET request using the `Job`'s ID to get a list of all the `Result` associated with it. I've tried to give custom implementations for `retrieve(self, request, pk=None)` and `get_queryset(self)` but so far my approaches have not worked. Ideally, I'd like to call a url such as `localhost:8000/api/results/15` where `15` would be the object id of the `Job` that was created. If there are 5 `Result` objects that have the `job` ForeignKey field set as the `Job` object with an ID of `15`, a list of those 5 `Result`s would be returned in the response.

My parsed-down views.py and urls.py are below:

views.py

```
class ResultsView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ResultSerializer
    queryset = Result.objects.all()

    # one potential solution could be along the lines of this? Does not work tho
    def get_queryset(self):
        job_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        queryset = self.queryset.filter(job = job_id)
        return queryset
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()                   
router.register(r'results', views.ResultsView, 'my_project')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    # re_path('^api/results/(?P<job>.+)/$', views.ResultsView),
]
```

I think there may be an issue with attempting to match an integer ID to a ForeignKey field that is an object, but when I view `localhost:8000/api/results/` I am able to see an object where the ForeignKey field `job` is listed as a plain integer.

Is there an appropriate pattern for a task like this?

Comment: What's not working exactly in `retrieve`? Are you getting `Result` object instead of `Job`? Also if 15 is for Job id in `localhost:8000/api/results/15`, wouldn't it make more sense to use `localhost:8000/api/job/15/results`? `results/15` is saying 'I want the result object with result id 15'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between select\_related and prefetch\_related in Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to either use queryparam or kwarg other than pk in get_queryset because base retrieve method filters based on pk

```
def get_queryset(self):
  queryset = Result.objects.all()
  job_id = self.request.query_params.get('job_id')
  if job_id is not None:
      queryset = queryset.filter(job=job_id)
  return queryset
 #OR
def get_queryset(self):
  job_id = self.kwargs['job_id']
  queryset = self.queryset.filter(job = job_id)
  return queryset
```

If you are not using query param, router in urls.py needs to be changed to

```
router.register('results/(?P<job_id>.+)', ResultsView)
```

However, a better way would be using related name to retrieve all results with certain job id. You could do something like this in JobView

```
@action(detail="False")
def result_list(self,request, pk):
  job = Job.objects.get(id=pk)
  result_qs = job.result_set.all()
  serializer = ResultSerializer(result_qs, many=True)
  return Response(serializer.data)
```

The url for this would be /api/jobs/1/result_list/. Here related name is not defined so default is result_set. But we can define it in Result model.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ResultsView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ResultSerializer
    queryset = Result.objects.all()

    # one potential solution could be along the lines of this? Does not work tho
    def get_queryset(self):
        job_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        queryset = self.queryset.filter(job = job_id)
        return queryset
```

The problem here is that `self.kwargs['pk']` is an id for a Result, not a Job.

There are two possible solutions here:

1. Accept queryparams with your view so that the request can specify a job id with something like `http://localhost:8000/api/results/?job_id=1`. I suggest using [`django-filter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to do this with minimal amounts of code and high amounts of flexibility.
2. Add an [`@action`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) to your `JobsView` that allows you to make a request like `http://localhost:8000/api/jobs/1/results/` to get all the requests for a given job.