# Django Rest Framework: optimize nester serializers performance

Tags: django, performance, django-rest-framework, query-optimization, django-serializer

I have problem with my endpoint performance which returns around 40 items and response takes around 17 seconds.

I have model:

```
class GameTask(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField()
    description = RichTextUploadingField()
    ...
```

and another model like that:

```
class TaskLevel(models.Model):
    master_task = models.ForeignKey(GameTask, related_name="sub_levels", on_delete-models.CASCADE)
    sub_tasks = models.ManyToManyField(GameTask, related_name="master_levels")
    ...
```

So basicly I can have "normal" tasks, but when I create TaskLevel object I can add master_task as a task which gonna fasten other tasks added to sub_tasks field.

My serializers look like:

```
class TaskBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fields created by serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    ...

class TaskLevelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sub_tasks = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = TaskLevel

    def get_sub_tasks(self, obj: TaskLevel):
        sub_tasks = get_sub_tasks(level=obj, user=self.context["request"].user) # method from other module
        return TaskBaseSerializer(sub_tasks, many=True, context=self.context).data

class TaskSerializer(TaskBaseSerializer):
    levels_config = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = GameTask

    def get_levels_config(self, obj: GameTask):
        if is_mastertask(obj):
            return dict(
                sub_levels=TaskLevelSerializer(
                    obj.sub_levels.all().order_by("number"), many=True, context=self.context
                ).data,
                progress=get_progress(
                    master_task=obj, user=self.context["request"].user
                ),
            )
        return None
```

When I tried to measure time it turned out that `get_levels_config` method takes around 0.25 seconds for one multilevel-task (which contain 7 subtasks). Is there any way to improve this performance? If any more detailed methods are needed I will add them

Answer (score 2):

Your code might be suffering from N+1 problem. `TaskSerializer.get_levels_config()` performs database queries from `obj.sub_levels.all().order_by("number")`.

What happens when serializing multiple instances like:

```
TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
```

each instance calls `.get_levels_config()`

You can use `prefetch_related` & `selected_related`(more explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm)).

You will have to manually check for prefetched objects since you are using `SerializerMethodField`. There's also the functions `get_progress` & `get_sub_tasks` which I assume does another query.

---

Here are some examples that can be used around your code:

Prefetching:

```
GameTask.objects.prefetch_related("sub_levels", "master_levels")

# Accessing deeper level
GameTask.objects.prefetch_related(
    "sub_levels",
    "master_levels",
    "sub_levels__sub_tasks",
).select_related(
    "master_levels__master_task",
)
```

Checking prefetch:

```
def get_sub_tasks(self, obj: TaskLevel):
    if hasattr(obj, "_prefetched_objects_cache") and obj._prefetched_objects_cache.get("sub_tasks", None):
        return obj._prefetched_objects_cache
    return obj.sub_tasks.all()
```