# Can I use select_related Django QuerySet method in reverse relationships?

Tags: python, django, orm

```py
class A(Model):
  pass


class B(Model):
  a = ForeignKey(A)


B.objects.select_related("a")  # this works
A.objects.select_related("b")  # this doesn't
```

How do I make the second line work? Are there any ways to do the same thing in some other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `prefetch_related` since there could be multiple `B` instances referencing the same `A` instance

`A.objects.prefetch_related("b_set")`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31237071/3862325

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: Thanks. What should I do if I want to sort the QS by a field of related set, i.e. `.prefetch_related("b_set").order_by("b_set__field")`? It does not work

Comment: each `B` in `b_set` could have a different value for `field` but you can do `.prefetch_related("b_set").order_by("b__field")`