# How to use "Prefetch()" with "filter()" to reduce `SELECT` queries to iterate 3 or more models?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-prefetch

I have `Country`, `State` and `City` models which are chained by foreign keys as shown below:

```py
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class State(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Then, when I iterate `Country`, `State` and `City` models with [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) and [all()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.all) as shown below:

```py
                                  # ↓ Here ↓
for country_obj in Country.objects.all().prefetch_related("state_set__city_set"):
    for state_obj in country_obj.state_set.all(): # Here
        for city_obj in state_obj.city_set.all(): # Here
            print(country_obj, state_obj, city_obj)
```

3 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below. *I use PostgreSQL and these below are the query logs of PostgreSQL and you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries#answer-75031321) explaining how to enable and disable the query logs on PostgreSQL:

[image]

But, when I iterate with [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#filter) instead of `all()` as shown below:

```py
                                  # Here
for country_obj in Country.objects.filter().prefetch_related("state_set__city_set"):
    for state_obj in country_obj.state_set.filter(): # Here
        for city_obj in state_obj.city_set.filter(): # Here
            print(country_obj, state_obj, city_obj)
```

8 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below instead of 3 `SELECT` queries:

[image]

So, I use [Prefetch()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) with `filter()` to reduce 8 `SELECT` queries to 3 `SELECT` queries as shown below:

```py
for country_obj in Country.objects.filter().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('state_set', # Here
        queryset=State.objects.filter(),
        to_attr='state_obj'
    ),
    Prefetch('city_set', # Here
        queryset=City.objects.filter(),
        to_attr='city_obj'
    ),
):
    print(country_obj, country_obj.state_obj, country_obj.city_obj)
```

But, the error below occurs:

> AttributeError: Cannot find 'city_set' on Country object, 'city_set'
> is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

So, how can I use `Prefetch()` with `filter()` to reduce 8 `SELECT` queries to 3 `SELECT` queries?

Comment: From error message you're trying to prefetch `city_set` on `Country` object instead of `State`

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting prefetch objects

```
countries = Country.objects.filter().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('state_set', # Here
        queryset=State.objects.filter().prefetch_related(
            Prefetch("city_set",
            queryset=City.objects.filter(),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Then run everything with `all()` since it's already filtered

```
for country_obj in countries:
    for state_obj in country_obj.state_set.all():
        for city_obj in state_obj.city_set.all():
            print(country_obj, state_obj, city_obj)
```