DRF list api response so slow and cause CPU throttling
An API in my project works fine locally but when it is called in production, it slows the application's response time (all other APIs) and the container workload gets throttled for about 10 seconds.
here is my model.py:
class Event(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='events', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    other_organizers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='organized_events')
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='teached_events')
    sponsors = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='sponsored_events')
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    ...

view.py:
    @action(
        detail=False, 
        serializer_class=UserEventListSerializer, 
        url_path='user-events'
    )
    def user_events(self, request):
        '''
        Retrieves all events in which the user has participated.
        '''
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.request.query_params.get('username'))
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(user=user) | 
            Q(other_organizers=user) | 
            Q(teachers=user) | 
            Q(sponsors=user)
        )
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            page, many=True, context={'user': user, 'request': self.request}
        )
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

At first, I thought it was the filter query with Q and OR, but when I ran it in the Django shell (in production) it got the data fine. Also, I use the same serializer on some other APIs that work fine so it's not the serializer.
Does anyone have an idea what it might be ??

Is there a SELECT N+1 issue in this query? You're bringing in a bunch of related models, and that can cause a select for each model object that gets brought in.

I don't see any but I may be wrong and we suppose there is how can I avoid that? @NickODell

You can use select_related or prefetch_related to avoid SELECT N+1 issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm
