# PostgreSQL find activity in particular point of time

Tags: database, postgresql

I am using Postgresql 9.4. How can I find what queries were running or who were logged in  say 2 hous ago in Postgresql?

Also,   is there any other postgres forums where I can ask question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select * from pg_stat_activity` shows you sessions (and queries). But real time only. You can `cron` saving those stat to other table, or [enable logging level to save statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries) and connections to logs. But pg itself does not do that...