# Django ORM : how can i see last executed query on fly

Tags: python, django, orm

so lets say we have a simple query using django orm

```
filterd = User.objects.exclude(id = request.user.id ).filter(username=data['username'] )
```

this is suppose to return some objects but it returns none ! 
obviously i'm doing something wrong as i' not comfortable with django ORM yet , so i'll help alot to know what query is exactly executed in this line

i've searched around i found this

```
print(filter.query)
```

but i get

```
AttributeError: type object 'filter' has no attribute 'query'
```

i guess filter is None when no object is returned so ... what should i do ?

Comment: Notice that your ORM query is asigned to **filterd** and you are printing filterf. Extra d at the end of the variable name

Comment: @e4c5 thanx , i cant believe it was a typo !

Comment: @hretic keep in mind that you will get a `.query` string version from `.filter()` but you'll get an error if you perform an `.update()` or `.get()` (etc.). You could also enable logs in your DB engine and see the incoming queries in real time.

Comment: @Gocht so what is solution for update ? @ betonimig way ? or should i just do  a filter/select to see  the query and after that do a update ?

Comment: I had a similar need using PostgreSQL and to get the query executed in a `.update()` I enabled logs. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/722236/3945375 Then you can see incoming queries tracing the log file. You can look for the similar steps for your DB engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
from django.db import connection as conn
filterd = User.objects.exclude(id = request.user.id).filter(username=data['username'] )
# to execute query
print filterd
print conn.queries
```