# How to do query profiling in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, profiling

I want to trace all the queries done from Web Application to PostgreSQL server during a specific time interval.
I have searched all over the internet and found below 3 approaches:

1. pg_stat_activity which traces only current running queries
2. pg_stat_statements which traces all the queries(including queries running internally on postgresql server).
   Below is the snapshot of pg_stat_activity. I am hardly getting anything useful from this

[image]

3. Database logs (i think it will log all the queries)

But I want to trace the queries done from my web application.

how can i do that?

Comment: http://dalibo.github.io/pgbadger/  and https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Monitoring

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries. For you case  `SET LOCAL log_statement = 'all'` before  running queries should do what you need.

Comment: @RomanKonoval I enabled logging. But log file is full of internal system queries like this:
2017-03-03 13:07:04 IST LOG:  statement: SELECT
    (SELECT sum(blks_read) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 12066)) AS "Reads",
    (SELECT sum(blks_hit) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 12066)) AS "Hits"

 How can I log queries done from the web application?

Comment: Default settings in postgresql.conf should be to not log queries `log_statement = 'none'` and then you should enable logging in your application by executing `set local log_statement = 'all'` on a connection before you execute queries

Comment: @RomanKonoval this won't require PostgreSQL restart.....right?

Comment: `SET LOCAL` changes configuration setting till the end of current transaction so of cause it does not require restart.