# drop database fails in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

My code is

```
var cn = new NpgsqlConnection("host=localhost;database=dummydb;username=foo;password='bar';");
cn.Open();
var r1 = cn.Execute("drop database foo");
var r2 = cn.Execute("create database foo");
```

However r1 and r2 is -1. I have no idea why and I don't know how to check what went wrong

Comment: I don't know for sure, but certainly [PostgreSQL has logging](http://stackoverflow.com/q/722221/215552)?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Unfortunately it appears to be not logged.

Comment: See section "Notes": https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-dropdatabase.html

Comment: @barbsan: So how do I execute sql in C# without it being in a transnational block?

Comment: Get the error messages and read them. What do they say?