# PostgreSQL Logging on limited databases

Tags: postgresql, logging

How can I limit the PostgreSQL logging on the selected databases?
I have tried changing log-related parameters in `pg_Settings` table but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the configuration parameter for each database

```
ALTER DATABASE your_database_name
SET log_statement = 'all';
```

[log_statement documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT)

Comment: Thanks for quick response, here you mean to set log_statement to none in postgreSQL conf file and set log_statement to "all" for the databases we   want logging. is this understanding correct

Comment: @ShaliniGarg if your query has been solved,pls mark it as answer

Comment: @ShaliniGarg hope this link will be useful for further log related queries https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries