# How to retrieve all database sql executed from particular server?

Tags: postgresql

I am running an application in a particular server which updates a postgres database table.Is there any way that I can retrieve all the queries executed to that database (may be my table) from a -period of time if I have admin privilege?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the extension [pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html) which will give you a summary of the queries executed.

Note that the number of queries that are stored in the table `pg_stat_statements` is limited (the limit can be [configured](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html#idm46046811129152)). So you probably want to store a snapshot of that table on a regular basis. How often depends on your workload. Increasing `pg_stat_statements.max` means you can reduce the frequency of taking snapshots from that table.