# Log long-running queries in django

Tags: django, postgresql

We're running postgres and sometimes the django ORM generates long-running queries. You can log queries in postgres as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries). Any query generated by the log can be difficult to tie back to actual code that generated it.

Is there a good way of tying a query to the actual code?

Comment: apart of logging, you can use `pg_stat_statements`, its pg extension, very comfortable for querying

Comment: Thanks :). There is still the issue of understanding where the query comes from.

Comment: ah, sorry. of course. using `/* query identifier*/ SELECT ...` is not the option?..