# postgres: how to turn on logging?

Tags: postgresql, logging

I followed what is explained in [How to log PostgreSQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries) but the logging collector stays off.

```
    postgres=# show logging_collector;
    logging_collector
    -------------------
    off
    (1 row)
```

My postgresql.conf file Looks like this:

```
    listen_addresses = '*'
    tcpip_socket = true
    log_statement = 'all'
    log_connections = yes
    log_destination = 'syslog'
    logging_collector = on
    log_directory = '/var/log/pg_log'
    log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'
    log_truncate_on_rotation = true
    log_rotation_age = 1440
    client_min_messages = LOG
    log_min_messages = INFO
    log_min_error_statement = DEBUG5
    log_min_duration_statement = 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

often it is enough to

```
pg_reload_conf()
```

to re-read postgres.conf

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html

> `pg_reload_conf()`    Cause server processes to reload their
>   configuration files

but:

```
t=# select name,setting,unit,source,context from pg_settings where name = 'logging_collector';
       name        | setting | unit |       source       |  context
-------------------+---------+------+--------------------+------------
 logging_collector | on      |      | configuration file | postmaster
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-settings.html

> `postmaster` These settings can only be applied when the server starts,
>   so any change **requires restarting the server**. Values for these
>   settings are typically stored in the postgresql.conf file, or passed
>   on the command line when starting the server. Of course, settings with
>   any of the lower context types can also be set at server start time.

so it means you have to restart your cluster

Comment: Small typo - `pg_reload_config()` in the first code block should be `pg_reload_conf()` per the second highlight.

Comment: command to run to reload server with new configs: `SELECT pg_reload_conf();`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I followed [this documentation](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-log-queries-in-postgresql/#verifying-log-generation) and it didn't show me the query logs (which was my intention) but it didn't work. Then I added these parameters to the postgres.conf file and the logs were shown:

```
event_source = 'PostgreSQL'

log_statement = 'all'
```

Both are commented out by default.

Comment: This is relevant only for Windows.