# Log all PostgreSQL queries to a table, not a file

Tags: postgresql, logging

Through this question:

[How to log PostgreSQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries)

I know I can log PostgeSQL queries to a file, but what if I want to log those queries to a table rather than a file? I know that this is doable in Redshift and MySQL, but how do I achieve the same on PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

But you can use the `csvlog` format, rotate the log file regularly and load it into a table with `COPY`.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-CSVLOG) for details.

I think that it is a bad idea to log directly into a database, because the performance is bad enough that this is likely to become your performance bottleneck.