# Why is QueryRow().Scan() returning an empty string when it is not empty in table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I am trying to Query a single row from a PostgreSQL database table.

```golang
func getPrefix(serverID int64, db *sql.DB) string {
    var prefix string
    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT prefix FROM servers WHERE serverid = 1234").Scan(&prefix)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    spew.Dump(prefix)
    fmt.Println("Prefix is " + prefix)
    return prefix
}
```

Apparently, the variable `prefix` is an empty String, but when I query it in the database, it's not empty

```
You are now connected to database "mewbot" as user "postgres".
mewbot=# select * from servers;
 serverid | prefix
----------+--------
     1234 | ;
(1 row)


mewbot=#
```

My question is, why is it returning an Empty String when it should be `;`
All checks taken; I've made sure I'm connected to the same database et al

Comment: `fmt.Println(err.Error())` can be shortened to `fmt.Println(err)`

Comment: What is the data type of the `prefix` column?

Comment: @Flimzy Data type of `prefix` column is text

Comment: @Dylee If you're certain you're connected to the same db, what happens if you prefix your table, in both Go and psql, with a schema name, for example `public.servers` or wherever the table is defined, do you still get the same result? And is the prefix column nullable, if so what is the output of `\pset null`?

Comment: @mkopriva I followed what you said and tried this `SELECT servers.prefix FROM public.servers WHERE serverid = 1234;` And it still didn't work, output of `\pset null` is 
`Null display is "".`

Comment: And you're using `lib/pq` as the dirver?

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, these are my imports `import (
 "database/sql"
 "fmt"

 "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
 _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)`

Comment: @Dylee I've tried your example code just now and I can't recreate the issue, everything works as it should. The problem must be somewhere in your setup / environment or in the way in which you execute your program... which makes it close to impossible to tell what's wrong from just the content of the question, since that all looks alright. https://imgur.com/a/bo0dI95

Comment: Okay, let me give more info
My main folder/workspace has only 1 folder and 1 file which are

`utils/utils.go`[Here](https://pastiebin.com/5dbdc1318a4c1)

and

`main.go`[Here](https://pastiebin.com/5dbdc16c8942a)

Finally, I am running my code with `go run main.go` from the main folder

Comment: Also @mkopriva in my table, `serverid` is of type `bigint` and not `int`, just to point out because in your screenshot, it's of type `int`

Comment: The id you pass in go does not match the id you got back from psql. `118456055842734083` is not `1234`.

Comment: sorry I just recently added that, it still doesn't work

Comment: @Dylee note also that the first version of the go code on pastebin that you've linked had `118456055842734083` as an `int` argument, however that number don't fit into an `int`. Please make sure your code is in order, compiles, and executes. You could also try [turning on logs for your queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries) and compare the logs against what you think should be executed.

Comment: @Dylee also please never ever, when you receive back a non-nil error, continue as if nothing happend. Your code should exit if it encounters an error, but instead your code continues right where it left off after printing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was not working because SSL mode was disabled on my server but I was trying to connect without specifying it was disabled.

Changing `postgres://postgres:7890@localhost:5432/mewbot` to `postgres://postgres:7890@localhost:5432/mewbot?sslmode=disable` solved my issue.