# Statement logging in PostgreSQL 12.1. Has something changed from earlier versions?

Tags: postgresql, logging, postgresql-12

I'm debugging some code that uses SQLAlchemy to interact with a PostgreSQL database. The errors I'm seeing suggest that PostgreSQL is receiving my SQL statements, but perhaps not in the order I intended. So, I thought I'd enable statement logging to see what PostgreSQL is actually getting.

I did that a few years ago, using the instructions in

[How to log PostgreSQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/722221/2144390)

and it worked just fine. (It must have, because I upvoted that question and the accepted answer.)

However, that was probably with PostgreSQL 9.x. This time I'm working with PostgreSQL 12.1. I added the following lines to "/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf":

```
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = '/tmp'
log_file_mode = 0777
log_min_duration_statement = 0
log_statement = 'all'
```

and restarted the PostgreSQL server. The log file gets created ...

```
gord@gord-dv7-xubuntu0:~$ ll /tmp/postgresql-2019-12-18_115629.log 
-rw-rw-rw- 1 postgres postgres 632 Dec 18 11:56 /tmp/postgresql-2019-12-18_115629.log
```

... and it contains some entries ...

```
gord@gord-dv7-xubuntu0:~$ cat /tmp/postgresql-2019-12-18_115629.log 
2019-12-18 11:56:30.478 MST [697] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-12-18 11:55:32 MST
2019-12-18 11:56:31.170 MST [689] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-12-18 11:56:32.832 MST [743] postgres@template1 LOG:  statement: 
2019-12-18 11:56:32.832 MST [743] postgres@template1 LOG:  duration: 43.323 ms
2019-12-18 11:56:33.459 MST [749] postgres@template1 LOG:  statement: 
2019-12-18 11:56:33.459 MST [749] postgres@template1 LOG:  duration: 0.257 ms
2019-12-18 11:56:34.021 MST [755] postgres@template1 LOG:  statement: 
2019-12-18 11:56:34.021 MST [755] postgres@template1 LOG:  duration: 0.460 ms
```

... but after running several queries like `select 2+2;` the above is all that ever appears in the log file.

I also ran the `ALTER DATABASE` command suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45563564/2144390), i.e.,

```sql
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET log_statement = 'all';
```

and restarted the server (again), but still I get nada.

Has something changed in the more recent versions of PostgreSQL that hasn't been included in the aforementioned answers?

**Edit**

As noted in the comments to the answer, this particular box had both PostgreSQL 12.1 server *and* PostgreSQL 10.11 server installed on it. I was editing the configuration file for 12.1, but my application was connecting to 10.11. The settings I was using were correct, they were just applied to the wrong copy of postgresql.conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anything has changed.  I get this in 12.1 with your settings:

```
2019-12-18 15:28:56.365 EST [20298] LOG:  statement: select 2+2;
2019-12-18 15:28:56.365 EST [20298] LOG:  duration: 0.373 ms
2019-12-18 15:28:57.409 EST [20298] LOG:  statement: select 2+2;
2019-12-18 15:28:57.409 EST [20298] LOG:  duration: 0.111 ms
2019-12-18 15:28:58.370 EST [20298] LOG:  statement: select 2+2;
2019-12-18 15:28:58.370 EST [20298] LOG:  duration: 0.163 ms
```

What client are you using to submit your queries?  Maybe your client inspects SQL and decided that `select 2+2;` was dumb and it wasn't going to submit it as written (but then decided to submit a blank query instead?)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've just been using`psql` for testing. I also tried more substantial queries like `select * from tablename`.

Comment: Do you get a "statement:" line, but with no statement text given, for the more substantial queries?

Comment: Nope. Those log entries are written immediately after the service starts up. Anything I do leaves the log file untouched.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood.  I thought you got the null entries for each query executed.  In that case, I'd run `\drds` in "psql" to see any other overrides that may be in effect.  ALTER USER takes priority over ALTER DATABASE.

Comment: Thanks again. I've just discovered that the box actually appears to have both 12.1 *and* 10.11 servers on it. I think that when I type `psql` at the command line it launches the 12.1 version of `psql` but then connects to the 10.11 version of the server. Just confirming that now ....

Comment: Yup, that was it. I should have been changing "/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf" instead of  "/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf". 