# How to view if a table has been read recently in postgres 12

Tags: postgresql-12

How can I manage to view if a table has been read recently in postgresql 12 ?
I will need something like "select lastdateread from stat_table"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Statement logging in PostgreSQL 12.1. Has something changed from earlier versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59399024/statement-logging-in-postgresql-12-1-has-something-changed-from-earlier-version)

Comment: Did you also check on [dba.se]?

Comment: I need somethig like select date:last read from stattable

Comment: nothing found yet