# Cannot reduce "SELECT" queries with "select_related()" and "prefetch_related()" in one-to-one relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-select-related, django-prefetch-related

I have `Person` and `PersonDetail` models in **one-to-one relationship** as shown below. *I use **Django 3.2.16**:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PersonDetail(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # Here
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.age) + " " + self.gender
```

Then, I have 5 objects for `Person` and `PersonDetail` models each:

[image]

[image]

Then, I iterate `PersonDetail` model from `Person` model as shown below:

```py
for obj in Person.objects.all():
    print(obj.persondetail)
```

Or, I iterate `PersonDetail` model from `Person` model with [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) as shown below:

```py
for obj in Person.objects.select_related().all():
    print(obj.persondetail)
```

Or, I iterate `PersonDetail` model from `Person` model with [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) as shown below:

```py
for obj in Person.objects.prefetch_related().all():
    print(obj.persondetail)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
32 Male
26 Female
18 Male
27 Female
57 Male
```

Then, 6 `SELECT` queries are run as shown below for all 3 cases of the code above. *I use PostgreSQL and these below are the query logs of PostgreSQL and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries#answer-75031321) explaining how to enable and disable the query logs on PostgreSQL:

[image]

So, I cannot reduce 5 `SELECT` queries with `select_related()` and `prefetch_related()` in **one-to-one relationship** in Django.

So, is it impossible to reduce `SELECT` queries with `select_related()` and `prefetch_related()` in one-to-one relationship in Django?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to specify the name of the related field which in this case is `persondetail`, so:

```py
for obj in Person.objects.select_related("persondetail").all():
    print(obj.persondetail)
```